# Python list condition - it is not empty - error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list part of an if clause:

```
 if context and a in b :
```

If the list is empty I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I can check if the list is empty with no issues with no errors using:

```
   if not context:
```

But I need the vice-versa working. I tried also

```
if context is not None
```

but the same error.
I don't understand why using not is working and without is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if context is not None` is comparing the object reference to 'None', not checking if the object itself is empty. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816363/if-a-vs-if-a-is-not-none) may help you understand it better.

Comment: thanks, but still not answer my question why 'if context' gives an error and 'if not context' is ok