# How to shorten the "is not None" in the if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pep8

In Python3, the `Truth Value Testing` in PEP8 says that for `if A is None:`, it can be converted to `if not A:`. Like so, since the code below looks so messy and hard to grasp at once, can it be expressed more succinct in one way or another?

`if A is not None and B is not None and C is not None:`

Comment: You have your logic reversed. `if A is None` can _sometimes_ be replaced by `if not A`, and `if A is not None` can _sometimes_ be replaced be `if A`, depending on the possible values of `A`. So it might be appropriate to replace your `if` statement with `if A and B and C` depending on the context.

Comment: `if A:` and `if A is not None:` are **not** semantically equivalent. I'm pretty sure PEP8 does *not* say this, since this isn't an issue of style.

Comment: `A = 0` -- > `if A:` would not enter the if-block. `if A is not None:` would enter the if-block

Comment: I edited the logic as you've pointed out! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with superbeck using `any()` or `all()` but you cal also check if `None` exist in a list including `A`, `B`, `C`

`if not (None in [A,B,C]):` or more intuitively `if None not in [A, B, C]:`  (Blckknght)

---

side note (deeper dive)

Either way I would discourage using `if A and B and C:` because `if A is not None` and `if A` does different thing.

`if A:` calls `A.__nonzero__()` and uses return value of that function.

`if A is not None` is tests identity in Python. Because there is one and only one instance of None present in a running Python script/program

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816363/if-a-vs-if-a-is-not-none) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python)

Comment: The `__nonzero__` name is in Python 2 only. It's replaced by `__bool__` in Python 3.

Comment: You can also use `if None not in [A, B, C]` in your solution. (`X not in Y` is an alternative spelling to `not X in Y`.)

Answer (score 3):

any() and all() can be used with a comprehension to help in these cases also.

```
if all([x is not None for x in [A,B,C]]):
```