# python "if len(A) is not 0" vs "if A" statements

Tags: python, pep8

My colleague uses this way in conditions

```
if len(A) is not 0:
    print('A is not empty')
```

I prefer this one

```
if A:
    print('A is not empty')
```

What is prop-cons arguments?

Her point is that first way is more straight-forward way to show what she exactly wants. My point is that my way is shorter.

Also first way is 2 times faster then my one:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('len(A) is not 0', setup='A=[1,2,3]')
0.048459101999924314
>>> timeit.timeit('bool(A)', setup='A=[1,2,3]')
0.09833707799998592
```

But

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('if len(A) is not 0:\n  pass', setup='A=[1,2,3]')
0.06600062699999398
>>> timeit.timeit('if A:\n  pass', setup='A=[1,2,3]')
0.011816206999810674
```

second way 6 times faster! I am confused how `if` works :-)

Comment: `if len(A) is not 0:` is dangerous because it is not guaranteed that the references are identical (`is` and `is not` do reference checks). `if A` tests the truthiness (emptiness) and is safe.

Comment: please have a look at this post.. [if A vs if A is not None:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816363/if-a-vs-if-a-is-not-none)

Comment: Personally I find your way more intuitive and straight-forward.

Comment: I thought that for integers "is" check is guaranteed to be "==" check. Can you show me an example when they do not match?

Comment: Shouldn't be using `is not 0` in any case. It should be `!=0`.

Comment: @vladimirfol: that's implementation specific.  Can you show me a statement in the python doc. where it says the are guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: @vladimirfol `x = 257; x is 257` fails. CPython interns only small integers.

Comment: @L3viathan: In Idle (3.6.6) this is `True`. It fails for me if I write the statements in different lines.

Comment: @Matthias In other words, it cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score 21):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide is clear about it:

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.
>
> ```
> Yes: if not seq:
>      if seq:
>
> No:  if len(seq):
>      if not len(seq):
> ```

Comment: But be careful with Numpy arrays: while `bool([0])` and `bool([False])` evaluate to `True`, `bool(numpy.array([0]))` and `bool(numpy.array([False]))` evaluate to `False`, so you should use `len` explicitly in this particular case.

Comment: I agree and disagree at the same time, PEP its a convention and we should be aware of it, but not a rule. There is another perspective, which I like to follow nowadays: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070199/6485445

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that if A = 42, your colleague code would raise an error

```
object of type 'int' has no len()
```

while your code would just execute whatever comes after the if.

Comment: Arguably if the code is *expecting* a list, that’s something of a nonissue.

Comment: That's true, but if you use this all the time, i'll guarantee you, there will be a time where you get something else than a list as the input of this, and you might lose quite some time debugging.

Comment: Well, on the contrary, this would raise a visible exception due to an unexpected type, rather than silently swallowing the problem.

Comment: @StatisticDean i'm not sure if you're saying that's a good thing or a bad thing - it seems to me that in general you want your code to error when your input is not what you expected - which is a point in favour of the 'colleague code' (although the OPs code is the correct python implementation, as the other answers have said)

Comment: @Stael I'm not taking a stance on whether it's good or bad, just pointing out the difference. In general, I would agree with you on having an error is better than having your code execute in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
if len(A) is not 0:
    print('A is not empty')
```

2.

```
if A:
    print('A is not empty')
```

the difference between first way and second way is that you can use len(A) only for structure like list,tuples,dictionary as they support the len() fuction but you can not use the len() fuction for data or like characters, strings, integers(numbers).

for example:

len(123), len(abc), len(123abc) : will raise an error.

but,
  list = [1,2,3,4,5]

len(list) will not raise an error

```
if A:
    statement  # this is useful while our only concern is that the variable A has some value or not
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the same thing.
If you compare this:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('if len(A) is not 0:\n  pass', setup='A=[1,2,3]'))
print(timeit.timeit('if A:\n  pass', setup='A=[1,2,3]'))
```

You will see that your method is faster.
Plus your method is a more pythonic way.

Comment: haaah, why is it faster? I thought if makes bool evaluation

Comment: 0.066 vs 0.0118 seconds! 6 times faster! I am confused now how `if` works :-)

Comment: It is faster because it uses one built-in function to compute "len(A) > 0" instead of several. At least I think, I can dig a bit to be sure if  interested.