# assert true vs assert is not None

Tags: python, automated-tests

I am working on some automated tests with a colleague and we wondered whether there were any differences in our approaches.

We have a method that returns a HTTP response object. Occasionally, it might return None, but normally an object.

The original code is:

```
self.assertTrue(response)
```

But I felt it might be more readable to have:

```
assert response is not None
```

I looked into the differences in the docs on truthyness, so I'm aware of things that would return true that aren't necessarily None. However, for the most part, both would work. And a lot of the existing tests are asserting true rather than asserting not none.

Is there any reason why one technique would work better than the other?

Comment: My personal opinion is that `is not None` is more precise and should therefore preferred. I would not use `self.assertTrue` because this is just misleading. If you want a more "lazy" assertion, then use `assert response` instead. But this is just my personal opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if A vs if A is not None:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816363/if-a-vs-if-a-is-not-none)

Comment: @Tim: It's sort of related, though if it went with if A is true vs if A is not None. I know there's not a huge difference, or maybe there is

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### tldr;

There is a functional difference in general, though in your particular case the execution result will be the same for both techniques. It now depends only on your willingness to be either explicit or concise.

### Full answer

Assuming that `a` is a variable in Python, *there is* a difference between:

```
assert a
```

and

```
assert a is not None
```

In the fist case, you are evaluating **the return of the call to the `bool()` buit-in** on the object, which follows multiple strategies to get a result, as it was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816363/if-a-vs-if-a-is-not-none).

This evaluates *only* according to the object's class implementation. Did you have a look on the class of your `response` object? It will tell you how `bool(response)` behaves.

In the second case, your are evaluating **`a` as not being `None`**. This is completely different. For example, an empty `list` will evaluate to `False` but is not `None`:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a is not None
True
>>> assert a is not None
>>> assert a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

If your response object is a sub-class derived from `list`, then it will probably behave the same way, so evaluating the emptiness of `response` is not equivalent to evaluating `response` as `None`.

In your case, I guess that your `response` object is provided by the `request` library. If so, then yes, in your particular case, both techniques are functionally equivalent, though you should notice a tiny performance gain evaluating against `None`.