# bool() vs is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I have two functions that return a bool. The first is using `bool()` and the second is using `is not None`.

```
def func_1(x) -> bool:
    return bool(x)

def func_2(x) -> bool:
    return x is not None

foo = "something"
bar = None

print(func_1(foo))
print(func_2(foo))
print("-----")
print(func_1(bar))
print(func_2(bar))
```

Here is the output

```
True
True
-----
False
False
```

Is there a difference between `is not None` and `bool()` in this instance? Is there something I may want to consider when using one or the other?

Comment: Try passing an empty string as the argument :)

Comment: Or try passing zero

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7816363/3001761.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the effect of `bool` on various types (not comprehensive):

- numeric types: False if 0, True otherwise
- sequence type (list, tuple, etc): False if empty, True otherwise
- object: False if None, true otherwise

(Note that if `None` is assigned to a variable that previously referred to a sequence type, the semantics will change from 2nd to 3rd bullet above).

Here's the effect of `is not None`:

- variable assigned to be None: False
- other: True

Comment: This, added to the other two answers, makes the explaination quite complete, I guess this deserves my +1

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference between `is not None` and `bool()` in this instance?

Yes! Check the Python documentation [`here`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), you will find that some values are *falsey* even beeing different from `None`.

---

Just as an example:

```
>>> 0 != None
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool), using bool function, all following will return False :

1. None
2. False
3. Zero
4. Operators...

Comment: "Operators"? What kind of operators can you check for truth values?

Comment: It can be empty objects, empty arrays... So just the brackets...

Comment: Ah, they're not usually thought of as operators. It usually refers to `+-/*%` etc