# "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" While saving a keras/tensorflow Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**Tensorflow version used: 2.13.0**

**Error details:**

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In \[481\], line 1
\----\> 1 titanic_model.save('titanic_model.keras')
2 reloaded = tf.keras.models.load_model('titanic_model.keras')

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.\<locals\>.error_handler(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
67     filtered_tb = \_process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
\---\> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71 finally:
72     del filtered_tb

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\layers\\preprocessing\\index_lookup.py:839, in IndexLookup.save_assets(self, dir_path)
838 def save_assets(self, dir_path):
\--\> 839     if self.input_vocabulary:
840         # Vocab saved in config.
841         # TODO: consider unifying both paths.
842         return
843     vocabulary = self.get_vocabulary(include_special_tokens=True)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**The above error occured while doing this:**

titanic_model.save('titanic_model.keras')

It looks like that error is occuring because of comparing vocabulary to a bool created during StringLookup, which I am creating as follows:

```
for name, input_ in inputs.items():
    if input_.dtype == tf.float32:
        continue

    
    lookup = layers.StringLookup(vocabulary = np.unique(titanic_features[name]), output_mode =  'one_hot', name = "string_lookup_" + name) # 
    # lookup.adapt(titanic_features[name])
    print(lookup.get_vocabulary())
    # one_hot = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens = lookup.vocabulary_size())

    x = lookup(input_)
    # x = one_hot(x)
    all_inputs.append(x)
```

If I try to learn the vocabulary by adapting the layer to the feature as follows, then the error disappears:

```
for name, input_ in inputs.items():
    if input_.dtype == tf.float32:
        continue

    
    lookup = layers.StringLookup(output_mode = 'one_hot', name = "string_lookup_" + name) #vocabulary = np.unique(titanic_features[name]), 
    lookup.adapt(titanic_features[name])
    print(lookup.get_vocabulary())
    # one_hot = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens = lookup.vocabulary_size())

    x = lookup(input_)
    # x = one_hot(x)
    all_inputs.append(x)
```

Python Version used: 3.11.0

Please find my notebook attached here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1okGXF8kr7faeGijPittyAqJt9i60SUKn?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues while trying to save a Model with a TextVectorization preprocessing layer. Thanks for the solution, it worked for me!

tf: 2.13.0
python: 3.10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I didn't provide a solution...I want to understand this behaviour of TensorFlow.

Comment: I meant the workaround you found with the .adapt() method

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue. It seems fixed in newer versions. You could, however, just edit the line of code in your local file system yourself so you don't need to update tensorflow as a whole.

The error is in the package https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v3.0.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/index_lookup.py

In the newer version the code looks like this:

```py
def save_assets(self, dir_path):
    if self.input_vocabulary **is not None**:
```

Whereas in the older version the code was:

```py
def save_assets(self, dir_path):
    if self.input_vocabulary:
```

In the older version it checked if the vocabulary evaluates to "true", in the newer version it correctly checks whether the vocabulary is present.

Comment: Thanx @Matthias....I understand the issue now. Since numpy arrays (`self.input_vocabulary`) can't be converted to Python bools, `if self.input_vocabulary:` will throw an error when I am "manually" providing the vocabulary. Please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816363/if-a-vs-if-a-is-not-none) about boolean comparison in Python.