# Any alternative way to check if there is any attribute in python?

Tags: python, attributes

```
a = SomeClass()
if hasattr(a, 'property'):
        a.property
```

Is this the only way to check if there is a property or not? Is there any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can just try to access it and catch `AttributeError` in case it doesn't exist.

```
try:
    a.foo
except AttributeError:
    ...
```

Comment: I haven't worked with much multithreading code, but it seems like this would also be the only threadsafe way to handle this. Is that correct? I mean, it seems like another thread could delete `a.foo` some time between `hasattr(a, 'foo')` and `a.foo` calls whereas this would be atomic.

Answer (score 8):

You could just use the property and catch the `AttributeError` exception if it doesn't exist. But using `hasattr` is also a reasonable approach.

A potential issue with catching the exception is that you can't easily distinguish between the attribute not existing, and it existing but when you call it some code is run and *that* code raises an `AttributeError` (perhaps due to a bug in the code).

You may also want to look at these related questions for more information on this topic:

- [How to know if an object has an attribute in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python)
- [hasattr() vs try-except block to deal with non-existent attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903130/hasattr-vs-try-except-block-to-deal-with-non-existent-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
if 'property' in a.__dict__:
    a.property
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant either but for the sake of completeness using `dir()` also works even when `__dict__` is not defined for the object:

```
if 'property' in dir(a):
    a.property
```

See also [What's the biggest difference between `dir()` and `__dict__` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361256/whats-the-biggest-difference-between-dir-and-dict-in-python)