# Django: is there a way to know if a url is valid in the application?

Tags: python, django

Here's my goal:

- the user wants to login
- I make a button on each page with the urlback as a parameter, for example if we are on the page `http://olivier.life/today`, the button to login will have an url like `http://olivier.life/login?back=today`
- the user logs in
- once the user is logged in, i check if there's a "`back`" in the "`GET`" request. if so then I make a redirect to the url in the `GET`

My problem is a security problem: I just want to know if the URL in the `GET` is part of my application (is valid for one of the URLs in the `urls.py` file).

How to do this?

Comment: So you have the list of all acceptable URLs?

Comment: You can use the `resolve` function to know if the URL is acceptable by your urls.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve). There's an example that's very close to this use case in the docs. I think for your case you want something like:

```
def some_view(request):
    redirect_target = request.GET.get('back')
    if redirect_target:
        try:
            resolve_match = django.core.urlresolvers.resolve(redirect_target)
        except django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404:
            # do something on bad input
        else:
            return django.shortcuts.redirect(redirect_target)
    else:
        # empty string redirect target, or not provided at all
        # do something else
```

Comment: I'm having a problem: if you use the translation url system here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/ you will see you add patterns like `urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(...)`. The problem is that the base url **without** the language is not taken in account ie: `resolve('/fr/produits/')` works, `resolve('/uk/produits/')` works, but `resolve('/produits/')` doesnt work and raises 404.

Comment: For the sake of any future readers - this answer will not work easily with the i18n framework, but the answer here looks good to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32739937/2337736

Answer (score 1):

You can use the urlresolver's resolve method, the method throws an exception if it can't resolve an URL, you can read more about urlresolver [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404

def yourView(request):
  try:
    if hasattr(request.GET, 'back'):
      resolve(request.GET['back'])
      return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['back'])
  except Resolver404:
      return Response('some other thing')
```

Comment: Use `in` rather than `hasattr` if you want to test for presence in a dict-like object such as `request.GET`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper it's more a question of personal preference, there is no benefit in it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748678/which-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-the-existence-of-an-attribute

Comment: You're not checking for an attribute. `request.GET.back` is not expected to work. `request.GET` is an instance of a subclass of `dict`, and `in` is the correct way to test for membership in a dict.

Comment: Just to be explicit for anyone else reading this - this is not just a disagreement about style. The posted code is incorrect. `hasattr` will not report `True` when checking a `QueryDict` object such as `request.GET` for a key. I am not downvoting because the important part of the answer (using `resolve`) is correct, but the `if hasattr(request.GET, 'back')` check will always return `False`