# Django i18n_patterns: resolve() doesnt work as expected

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, internationalization

After solving this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705698/django-is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-url-is-valid-in-the-application), there's another one: if you use the translation url system here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/ you will see you add patterns like `urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(...)`.

The problem is that the base url **without** the language is not taken in account ie:

- `resolve('/fr/produits/')` works,
- but `resolve('/produits/')` doesnt work and raises 404.

How to solve this?

Here are my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^debug/?$', p_views.debug, name='debug'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^login/(\w*)', p_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin_site.urls)),
    url(r'^public/(?P<path>.*)$',
        'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT},
        name='url_public'
        ),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(_(r'^produits/detail/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$'),
        p_views.ProduitDetailView.as_view(), name='produits_detail'),
    url(_(r'^produits/'),
        p_views.IndexView.as_view(), name='produits_index'),
)
```

And here's the very simple URL-tester I've made (which corresponds to the `/debug` view):

```
def debug(req):

    def test(url):
        try:
            return u'<pre>{0} {1}</pre>'.format(url, resolve(url))
        except Resolver404:
            return u'<pre>{0} {1}</pre>'.format(url, 'None')

    response = HttpResponse()
    response.write(test('produits'))
    response.write(test('produits/'))
    response.write(test('/produits'))
    response.write(test('/produits/'))
    response.write(test('/fr/produits'))
    response.write(test('/fr/produits/'))
    response.write(test('/en/products/'))
    response.write(test('/sv/produkter/'))
    return response
```

Here's the `http://localhost:8000/debug` page:

```
produits None
produits/ None
/produits None
/produits/ None
/fr/produits None
/fr/produits/ ResolverMatch(func=produits.views.IndexView, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=produits_index, app_name=None, namespaces=[])
/en/products/ None
/sv/produkter/ None
```

The three lastest lines should all return `ResolverMatch(...)` because they are all valid URLs.

Comment: Related: [Django i18n default language without path prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13636604/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse Thank you, but I've already read it and it doesn't solve my problem. I want to do kinddof "reverse translation" to go from `/sv/produkter/` to `/fr/produits/` (to see it's a valid URL)

Comment: Yeah thats why I didn't mark it as a duplicate. I didn't manage to find an exact resolution and haven't the time to help im afraid

Comment: I've updated my question to show more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django's url resolvers only work on current language.
So you will need to switch language before attempting to solve an url in a specific language, using [`translation.activate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate).

For resolving the url, that means you must know the language beforehand, switch to it and only then resolve (basically what the localemiddleware will do for you).

For reversing the url, that means you should probably reverse the url using its name. You'll get back the url in current language. I cannot test right now, but it should work like this:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('fr')
reverse('produits_index')    # /fr/produits/
translation.activate('en')
reverse('produits_index')    # /en/products/
```

If you did manage to get a `ResolverMatch` object, you have the url name as an attribute on it, conveniently named `url_name`.

I hope it helps, I am a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do. Feel free to comment/edit your question and I'll try to update this answer.

---

Update by Olivier Pons

---

Here's the working solution:

here's my working solution, which is close to spectras, but works the way I wanted:

```
# (!) resolve() use current language
#     -> try to guess language then activate BEFORE resolve()
lg_curr = translation.get_language()
lg_url = get_language_from_path(url) or lg_curr
translation.activate(lg_url)
try:
    resolve(url)
    req.session['url_back'] = url  # no error -> ok, remember this
except Resolver404:
    pass
translation.activate(lg_curr)
```

...and then later on, after successful registration/login, if there's a `req.session['url_back']` then I remove it from session and make a redirect on it.

Comment: I've added my working solution so I can check your answer as valid **`:)`**

Comment: great! exactly what i was searching for and trying to figure out for a day now