# Django resolve() doesn't resolve with i18n urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-i18n, cookiecutter-django

- **Django**: 2.2.7
- **Python** 3.6.8

I have initiated a project using cookiecutter-django template. After that I translated to 4 languages and I included i18n for urls so that depending on accessing each one, I get it translated in a different language. For example:

- http://localhost:8000/home => Gets the home page in english (default)
- http://localhost:8000/en/home => Gets the home page in english
- http://localhost:8000/es/home => Gets the home page in spanish

The thing is that I started to apply TDD and made a test first:

**myapp/tests.py**:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve
from django_sftpbrowser.views import browse_page


# Create your tests here.
class BrowsePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_browse_url_resolves_to_browse_page(self):
        found = resolve('browse/')  # Tried also en/browse/
        self.assertEqual(found.func, browse_page)
```

But, although the URLs seem to work in the browser, when running this test I find this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_browse_url_resolves_to_browse_page (django_sftpbrowser.tests.BrowsePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/madtyn/PycharmProjects/corelli/django_sftpbrowser/tests.py", line 9, in test_browse_url_resolves_to_browse_page
    found = resolve('browse/')
  File "/home/madtyn/venvs/corelli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 24, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/madtyn/venvs/corelli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 568, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'path': path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'path': 'browse/'}
```

My urls are these below. You will notice the i18n url pattern which I believe in some way provoke the described error:

**config/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views import defaults as default_views
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(*[
    path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/home.html"), name="home"),
    path(
        "about/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/about.html"), name="about"
    ),
    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    # User management
    path("users/", include("corelli.users.urls", namespace="users")),

    # This relies on the 'django-allauth' pip3 package
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here

    path("browse/", include("myapp.urls", namespace="myappbrowser-root")),
    path("browse/<path:input_path>", include("myapp.urls", namespace="myappbrowser-resource")),

    # i18n:  sets a user’s language preference and redirects to a given URL
    # or, by default, back to the previous page
    path("i18n/", include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    # This allows the error pages to be debugged during development, just visit
    # these url in browser to see how these error pages look like.
    urlpatterns += [
        path(
            "400/",
            default_views.bad_request,
            kwargs={"exception": Exception("Bad Request!")},
        ),
        path(
            "403/",
            default_views.permission_denied,
            kwargs={"exception": Exception("Permission Denied")},
        ),
        path(
            "404/",
            default_views.page_not_found,
            kwargs={"exception": Exception("Page not Found")},
        ),
        path("500/", default_views.server_error),
    ]
    if "debug_toolbar" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        import debug_toolbar

        urlpatterns = [path("__debug__/", include(debug_toolbar.urls))] + urlpatterns
```

**myapp/urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import browse_page

app_name = 'myappbrowser'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', browse_page, name='myapp-root'),
    #path('<path:input_path>', browse_page, name='myapp-resource'),
]
```

**myapp/views.py**:

```
def browse_page(request, input_path=None):
    pass
```

I don't know what is wrong or what should I do. I tried reading django docs about resolve() and trying to understand the django source code for resolve(). I tried to force setting a value for urlconf in the resolve() method while debugging, but I failed.

Please help.

PS: I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738840/django-i18n-patterns-resolve-doesnt-work-as-expected) and tried django.utils.translation.activate() and django.utils.translation.trans_real.activate() with no luck. I guess it doesn't apply or that there is much difference between Django versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django i18n\_patterns: resolve() doesnt work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738840/django-i18n-patterns-resolve-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: I have just woke up in the morning and tried this. Doesn't seem to make a difference to use translation.activate() before using resolve. Also take into account I'm with Django 2.2.7