# Using isinstance() to check class variable's belonging

Tags: python, enums

I would like to use *isinstance()* method to identify class variable is it belongs to the given class.

I created an own *Enum()* base class to list class variables of subclasses.
I did't detail body of source code, not important.

```python
class Enum(object):

    @classmethod
    def keys(cls):
        pass  # Returns all names of class varables.

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        pass  # Returns all values of class varables

    @classmethod
    def items(cls):
        pass # Returns all class variable and its value pairs.

class MyEnum(Enum):
    MyConstantA = 0
    MyConstantB = 1

>>>MyEnum.keys()
['MyConstantA', 'MyConstantB']
```

I would like to use this one:

```python
>>>isinstance(MyEnum.MyConstantB, MyEnum)
True
```

Comment: Python has enums already, why roll your own class for this?

Comment: Python 3.4 has enums on board. For other versions you can use the port of [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

Comment: This kind of looks like you want to reimplement a dictionary.

Comment: If you don't care about how you check if a class got a certain attribute, this question might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748678/which-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-the-existence-of-an-attribute

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not true.  It can be done with metaclasses, for example the python implementation of enums is designed in this way.

Comment: @wim so `isinstance(SomeEnum.member, SomeEnum)` is true? That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @wim - alright; retracted, thanks. *Goes off to find out how and why...*

Comment: I have to use Python 2.6 and I would like to use this behavior that written above.

Comment: @DavidLantos ...then just use the backport, which is good from 2.4 up

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I can just drop into my package the _enum34_ and use it directly, Cheers guys the quick answer!

Comment: Or just install it via `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` became an official data type in Python 3.4, and [there is a backport here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), with [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html).

`isinstance()` works as you would like, and to get the names of the members you would use:

```
myEnum.__members__.keys()
```

While both `MyEnum['MyConstantA']` and `MyEnum(0)` would return the `MyEnum.MyConstantA` member.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that an ordinary dictionary can do what you want:

```
>>> myEnum = {'MyConstantA': 0, 'MyConstantB': 1}
```

Or let `enumerate` do the counting:

```
>>> myEnum = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(['MyConstantA', 'MyConstantB'])}
```

Then:

```
>>> myEnum.keys()
['MyConstantA', 'MyConstantB']
>>> myEnum.values()
[0, 1]
>>> myEnum.items()
[('MyConstantA', 0), ('MyConstantB', 1)]
>>> 'MyConstantB' in myEnum
True
```

---

In case you really want to write your own class, use `hasattr` to test the existence of class variables:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     bar = 5
...
>>> hasattr(Foo, 'bar')
True
```

Comment: The goal is to achieve the isinstance() usage. This implementation is a part of bigger structure, that's why would be great if isinstance() can work some way.