# Python programming;

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
a=[1, 2, 3, -2, -5, -6, 'geo'] 

for I in a:
    if I == star:
        continue
    if I<0:
        print('I=', I)
```

I don't know how to let my program  to distill the negative numbers and print only them avoiding strings. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think you are looking for. I fixed several formatting issues.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, -2, -5, -6, 'geo'] 

for I in a:
    if I == 'star':
        continue
    try:
        if I < 0:
            print('I=', I) 
    except TypeError:
        continue

# I= -2
# I= -5
# I= -6
```

Updated to catch only errors other than `TypeError`.

Comment: [Please don’t use `except: pass`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327/216074).

Comment: @poke. thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to print only negative integers.
Below code should do it:

```
a=[1, 2, 3, -2, -5, -6, 'geo']

for I in a:
    if type(I) is int:
        if I < 0:
            print('I=', I)
```

> Output:
>   I= -2
>   I= -5
>   I= -6

Comment: You should use `isinstance(I, int)` instead of checking for explicit type identity.

Comment: @poke there was already an answer mentioning isinstance() method, so I wrote different one. plus its easier to read and understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

[isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is the way to go.

```
    if isinstance(l, int) and l < 0:
        print('l=', l)
```

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the python idiom, but it seems to prefer `try...except...` above `isinstance`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024913/python-isinstance-vs-hasattr-vs-try-except-what-is-better

Comment: Agreed. Gave your answer a +1.