# Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to test if a key exists in a dictionary before updating the value for the key.
I wrote the following code:

```
if 'key1' in dict.keys():
  print "blah"
else:
  print "boo"
```

I think this is not the best way to accomplish this task. Is there a better way to test for a key in the dictionary?

Comment: Calling `dict.keys()` creates a list of keys, according to the documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys but I'd be surprised if this pattern wasn't optimised for, in a serious implementation, to translate to `if 'key1' in dict:`.

Comment: So I finally found out why many of my Python scripts were so slow :)  :(. That's because I've been using `x in dict.keys()` to check for keys. And that happened because the usual way to iterate over keys in Java is `for (Type k : dict.keySet())`, this habit causing `for k in dict.keys()` to feel more natural than `for k in dict` (which should still be fine in terms of performance?), but then checking keys becomes `if k in dict.keys()` too, which is a problem...

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev `if k in dict_:` tests for presence of k in the KEYS of dict_, so you still don't need `dict_.keys()`. (This has bit me, as it reads to me like its testing for a *value* in dict. But it isn't.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That's right, but not only do you not need it, it's not a good practice.

Comment: Try "key in dict"

Answer (score 5448, accepted):

[`in`](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) tests for the existence of a key in a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
d = {"key1": 10, "key2": 23}

if "key1" in d:
    print("this will execute")

if "nonexistent key" in d:
    print("this will not")
```

---

Use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to provide a default value when the key does not exist:

```
d = {}

for i in range(100):
    key = i % 10
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1
```

---

To provide a default value for *every* key, either use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) on each assignment:

```
d = {}

for i in range(100):
    d[i % 10] = d.setdefault(i % 10, 0) + 1
```

...or better, use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(100):
    d[i % 10] += 1
```

Comment: I usually just use `get` if I'm going to be pulling the item out of the dictionary anyway.  No sense in using `in` *and* pulling the item out of the dictionary.

Comment: I fully agree.  But if you only need to know if a key exists, or you need to distinguish between a case where the key is defined and a case where you are using a default, `in` is the best way of doing it.

Comment: @enkash provided the reference for Python 3. Here is the reference for Python 2.7: [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: get is a bad test if the key is equivalent to "False", like `0` for example. Learned this the hard way :/

Comment: I can't agree that this a complete answer as it doesn't mention that 'try'-'except' will be the fastest when number of key fails is sufficiently small.
See this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602945/4376643

Comment: You should probably also mention that `dict.has_key()`, [as described on Tutorialspoint here, for instance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_has_key.htm), has [been deprecated in Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html): "Removed. dict.has_key() – use the `in` operator instead."

Comment: the 2nd print statement will obviously not execute in this example!

Comment: using `if "key1" in d` has a time complexity of O(n) as "key1" will be matched with every element in the dict keys. Instead use try and except KeyError and directly access d["key1"] if it exists, you will get the value else it will raise an error which is also taken care by the except statement :) Hence it happens in constant time!

Comment: Good if you can guarantee that you are testing a dictionary...

```
no_dict="some state"
if "state" in no_dict:
    print("Has state.")
else:
    print("Hasn't state.")
```



Answer (score 1895):

Use `key in my_dict` directly instead of `key in my_dict.keys()`:

```
if 'key1' in my_dict:
    print("blah")
else:
    print("boo")
```

That will be much [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527984/452708) as it uses the dictionary's O(1) hashing as opposed to doing an O(n) linear search on a list of keys.

Comment: doesn't work on nested values.

Comment: @Mujtaba nor would `dict.keys()` (just to clarify)

Comment: This seems to not work for custom class/object where __hash__ is implemented unless the value is the exact same i.e. `===` and not just `==`

Answer (score 298):

You can test for the presence of a key in a dictionary, using the **in** keyword:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
'a' in d # <== evaluates to True
'c' in d # <== evaluates to False
```

A common use for checking the existence of a key in a dictionary before mutating it is to default-initialize the value (e.g. if your values are lists, for example, and you want to ensure that there is an empty list to which you can append when inserting the first value for a key). In cases such as those, you may find the [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) type to be of interest.

In older code, you may also find some uses of `has_key()`, a deprecated method for checking the existence of keys in dictionaries (just use `key_name in dict_name`, instead).

Answer (score 183):

You can shorten your code to this:

```
if 'key1' in my_dict:
    ...
```

However, this is at best a cosmetic improvement. Why do you believe this is not the best way?

Comment: This is *much* more than a cosmetic improvement.  The time to find a key using this method is O(1) whereas calling keys would generate a list and be O(n).

Comment: The O(1) does not seem quite right. Are you sure it's not something like O(log n)?

Comment: It's the complexity of a single dict lookup, which is on average O(1) and at worst O(n). .list() will always be O(n). https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: this also avoids an extra allocation. (important for making tight loops a bit faster)

Comment: @JasonBaker Calling `.keys` only generates a list or takes O(n) time (and memory) in 2.x. In 3.x, it creates a special view object, analogous to 2.x's `.iterkeys`. However, it still adds unnecessarily complexity and overhead.

Comment: What if the key isn't a string?

Answer (score 101):

For additional information on speed execution of the [accepted answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary/1602964#1602964) proposed methods (10 million loops):

- `'key' in mydict` elapsed time 1.07 seconds
- `mydict.get('key')` elapsed time 1.84 seconds
- `mydefaultdict['key']` elapsed time 1.07 seconds

Therefore using `in` or `defaultdict` are recommended against `get`.

Comment: totally agree that `get`'s 1.84s is < 1.07*2 ;-P

Answer (score 66):

I would recommend using the `setdefault` method instead.  It sounds like it will do everything you want.

```
>>> d = {'foo':'bar'}
>>> q = d.setdefault('foo','baz') #Do not override the existing key
>>> print q #The value takes what was originally in the dictionary
bar
>>> print d
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>> r = d.setdefault('baz',18) #baz was never in the dictionary
>>> print r #Now r has the value supplied above
18
>>> print d #The dictionary's been updated
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 18}
```

Comment: What does `setdefault` have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @hughdbrown "I wanted to test if a key exists in a dictionary before updating the value for the key."  Sometimes posts include code that generate a flurry of responses to something that's not quite the original goal.  To accomplish the goal stated in the first sentence, setdefault is the most effective method, even though it's not a drop-in replacement for the sample code posted.

Answer (score 60):

A dictionary in Python has a `get('key', default)` method. So you can just set a default value in case there isn't any key.

```
values = {...}
myValue = values.get('Key', None)
```

Comment: The `get` method's second argument is optional and defaults to`None` if not included, so `values.get('Key', None)` is the same as `values.get('Key')`.

Answer (score 56):

Using the [Python ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator/394814#394814):

```
message = "blah" if 'key1' in my_dict else "booh"
print(message)
```

Answer (score 51):

Use EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission):

```
try:
   blah = dict["mykey"]
   # key exists in dict
except KeyError:
   # key doesn't exist in dict
```

See other Stack Overflow posts:

- *[Using 'try' vs. 'if' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python)*
- *[Checking for member existence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204308/checking-for-member-existence-in-python)*

Comment: Try/except may be more expensive if it's likely that the key often doesn't exist. From the post you referenced: "[I]f you expect that 99 % of the time result will actually contain something iterable, I'd use the try/except approach. It will be faster if exceptions really are exceptional. If result is None more than 50 % of the time, then using if is probably better.[...][A]n if statement always costs you, it's nearly free to set up a try/except block. But when an Exception actually occurs, the cost is much higher." http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835844/1094092

Answer (score 33):

> Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary

To get the idea how to do that we first inspect what methods we can call on dictionary.

Here are the methods:

```
d={'clear':0, 'copy':1, 'fromkeys':2, 'get':3, 'items':4, 'keys':5, 'pop':6, 'popitem':7, 'setdefault':8, 'update':9, 'values':10}
```

---

```
Python Dictionary clear()        Removes all Items
Python Dictionary copy()         Returns Shallow Copy of a Dictionary
Python Dictionary fromkeys()     Creates dictionary from given sequence
Python Dictionary get()          Returns Value of The Key
Python Dictionary items()        Returns view of dictionary (key, value) pair
Python Dictionary keys()         Returns View Object of All Keys
Python Dictionary pop()          Removes and returns element having given key
Python Dictionary popitem()      Returns & Removes Element From Dictionary
Python Dictionary setdefault()   Inserts Key With a Value if Key is not Present
Python Dictionary update()       Updates the Dictionary
Python Dictionary values()       Returns view of all values in dictionary
```

---

The brutal method to check if the key already exists may be the `get()` method:

```
d.get("key")
```

The other two *interesting* methods `items()` and `keys()` sounds like too much of work. So let's examine if `get()` is the right method for us. We have our dict `d`:

```
d= {'clear':0, 'copy':1, 'fromkeys':2, 'get':3, 'items':4, 'keys':5, 'pop':6, 'popitem':7, 'setdefault':8, 'update':9, 'values':10}
```

Printing shows the key we don't have will return `None`:

```
print(d.get('key')) #None
print(d.get('clear')) #0
print(d.get('copy')) #1
```

We use that to get the information if the key is present or no.
But consider this if we create a dict with a single `key:None`:

```
d= {'key':None}
print(d.get('key')) #None
print(d.get('key2')) #None
```

Leading that `get()` method is not reliable in case some values may be `None`.

This story should have a happier ending. If we use the `in` comparator:

```
print('key' in d) #True
print('key2' in d) #False
```

We get the correct results.

We may examine the Python byte code:

```
import dis
dis.dis("'key' in d")
#   1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key')
#               2 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
#               4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
#               6 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis("d.get('key2')")
#   1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
#               2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (get)
#               4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key2')
#               6 CALL_METHOD              1
#               8 RETURN_VALUE
```

This shows that `in` compare operator is not just more reliable, but even faster than `get()`.

Comment: `.get()` can have a second argument for `default` value, that couldbe used to handle the issue where `key:None`.    example:  `d.get("key", False)`

Comment: `.get()` is the fastest way.
Another option is to assign in a `try`/`except` block

Answer (score 24):

**The ways in which you can get the results are:**

- if your_dict.has_key(key) [Removed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)
- if key in your_dict
- try/except block

**Which is better is dependent on 3 things:**

1. Does the dictionary 'normally has the key' or 'normally does not have the key'.
2. Do you intend to use conditions like if...else...elseif...else?
3. How big is dictionary?

Read More: http://paltman.com/try-except-performance-in-python-a-simple-test/

Use of try/block instead of 'in' or 'if':

```
try:
    my_dict_of_items[key_i_want_to_check]
except KeyError:
    # Do the operation you wanted to do for "key not present in dict".
else:
    # Do the operation you wanted to do with "key present in dict."
```

Answer (score 21):

### Python 2 only: (and Python 2.7 supports `in` already)

You can use the `has_key()` method:

```
if dict.has_key('xyz')==1:
    # Update the value for the key
else:
    pass
```

Comment: `.has_key()` has been [deprecated](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#replacing-dict-has-key); you should use `in` as shown in other answers.

Comment: BTW, I recommend reading **ALL** existing answers to an **OLD** question, before answering it. This answer added nothing, since the suggestion already existed in Michael's answer, from '09. (I don't mean to discourage an attempt to add something useful to a discussion. Keep trying.)

Answer (score 19):

Just an FYI adding to [Chris. B's (best) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary/1602964#1602964):

```
d = defaultdict(int)
```

Works as well; the reason is that calling `int()` returns `0` which is what `defaultdict` does behind the scenes (when constructing a dictionary), hence the name "Factory Function" in the documentation.

Comment: If you're creating a dictionary of counts, you should be using [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (assuming Python 2.7). And I used `defaultdict(lambda: 0)` instead of `defaultdict(int)` because I think it's clearer what's going on; the reader doesn't need to know you get `0` if you call `int()` without arguments. YMMV.

Answer (score 9):

A Python dictionary has the method called `__contains__`. This method will return True if the dictionary has the key, else it returns False.

```
>>> temp = {}

>>> help(temp.__contains__)

Help on built-in function __contains__:

__contains__(key, /) method of builtins.dict instance
    True if D has a key k, else False.
```

Comment: It is very bad practice to call `__contains__` directly. The correct way of doing it, is to use `in` operator, which is the `containment check` that invokes the `__contains__` function.

Comment: @user1767754 I'm using `foo = x['foo'] if x.__contains__('foo') else 'bar'`. Any ideas how would might use the `in` operator as part of this expression?

Comment: `foo = x['foo'] if 'foo' in x else 'bar'`

Answer (score 6):

Another way of checking if a key exists using Boolean operators:

```python
d = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
keys = 'abcd'

for k in keys:
    x = (k in d and 'blah') or 'boo'
    print(x)
```

This returns

```
>>> blah
>>> blah
>>> boo
>>> boo
```

**Explanation**

First, you should know that in Python, `0`, `None`, or objects with zero length evaluate to `False`. Everything else evaluates to `True`. Boolean operations are evaluated left to right and return the operand not True or False.

Let's see an example:

```
>>> 'Some string' or 1/0
'Some string'
>>>
```

Since `'Some string'` evaluates to `True`, the rest of the `or` is not evaluated and there is no division by zero error raised.

But if we switch the order `1/0` is evaluated first and raises an exception:

```
>>> 1/0 or 'Some string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>>
```

We can use this for pattern for checking if a key exists.

```
(k in d and 'blah')
```

does the same as

```
if k in d:
    'blah'
else:
    False
```

This already returns the correct result if the key exists, but we want it to print 'boo' when it doesn't. So, we take the result and `or` it with `'boo'`

```
>>> False or 'boo'
'boo'
>>> 'blah' or 'boo'
'blah'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the dictionary and get the name of key you want to find in the dictionary. After that, check if it exist or not using `if` condition:

```
dic = {'first' : 12, 'second' : 123}
for each in dic:
    if each == 'second':
        print('the key exists and the corresponding value can be updated in the dictionary')
```

Comment: check over the code because the output for this is `it is exist` and `not exist`

Comment: why using a dictionary at all if this is to perform linear search?