# How to check if a name/value pair exists when posting data?

Tags: python, django

I'm not able to find the proper syntax for doing what I want to do. I want to do something if a name/value pair is not present. Here is the code in my view:

```
if (!request.POST['number']):
    # do something
```

What is the proper way to accomplish something like the above? I am getting a syntax error when I try this.

Comment: Assuming you're new to Python, not only to Django. First, `request.POST` in Django is like a normal Python *dictionary*. So you need to find out *what is the proper syntax to test the presence of a key in a dictionary*. Once you know that, you can google the right thing and find quite a few very similar questions that have been asked on StackOverflow already (for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/what-is-a-good-way-to-test-if-a-key-exists-in-python-dictionary).

Answer (score 57):

@Thomas gave you the generic way, but there is a shortcut for the particular case of getting a default value when a key does not exist.

```
number = request.POST.get('number', 0)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if 'number' not in request.POST:
    number = 0
else:
    number = request.POST['number']
```

Answer (score 31):

Most logically:

```
if not 'number' in request.POST:
```

Python convention:

```
if 'number' not in request.POST:
```

Both work in exactly the same way.

Comment: What is the resource that you use for python conventions?

Answer (score 3):

What I have used many times is the following in my **view**:

```
def some_view(request):

    foobar = False

    if request.GET.get('foobar'):
        foobar = True

    return render(request, 'some_template.html',{
        'foobar': foobar,
    })
```

Then, in my **template** I can use the following URL syntax to set `foobar`:

```
<a href="{% url 'view_name_in_urls' %}?foobar=True">Link Name</a>
```

Also, since we returned the `foobar` variable from the **view** above, we can use that in the **template** with other logic blocks (great for navigation!):

```
<li class="nav-item">
    {% if foobar %}
        <a class="nav-link active" ....
    {% else %}
        <a class="nav-link" ....
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom decorator to achieve this and throw an error if the field's requested fields are not sent from the front-end.

```
from typing import List
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response


def required_fields(dataKey: str, fields: List):
    def decorator_func(og_func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            data = None
            if dataKey == 'data':
                data = request.data
            elif dataKey == 'GET':
                data = request.GET
            for field in fields:
                if field not in data:
                    return Response('invalid fields', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            return og_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator_func
```

And now you can do:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@required_field('data',['field1', 'field2']) # use 'GET' instead of 'data' to check for a GET request.
def some_view(request):
data = request.data
... do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = request.POST.get('number', false)
```

For me this is much cleaner and readable. but it is same with

```
number = request.POST.get('number', 0)
```