# Exposing `defaultdict` as a regular `dict`

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper, defaultdict

I am using `defaultdict(set)` to populate an internal mapping in a very large data structure. After it's populated, the whole structure (including the mapping) is exposed to the client code. At that point, I don't want anyone modifying the mapping.

And nobody does, intentionally. But sometimes, client code may by accident refer to an element that doesn't exist. At that point, a normal dictionary would have raised `KeyError`, but since the mapping is `defaultdict`, it simply creates a new element (an empty set) at that key. This is quite hard to catch, since everything happens silently. But I need to ensure this doesn't happen (the semantics actually doesn't break, but the mapping grows to a huge size).

What should I do? I can see these choices:

1. Find all the instances in current and future client code where a dictionary lookup is performed on the mapping, and convert it to `mapping.get(k, {})` instead. This is just terrible.
2. "Freeze" `defaultdict` after the data structure is fully initialized, by converting it to `dict`. (I know it's not really frozen, but I trust client code to not actually write `mapping[k] = v`.) Inelegant, and a large performance hit.
3. Wrap `defaultdict` into a `dict` interface. What's an elegant way to do that? I'm afraid the performance hit may be huge though (this lookup is heavily used in tight loops).
4. Subclass `defaultdict` and add a method that "shuts down" all the `defaultdict` features, leaving it to behave as if it's a regular `dict`. It's a variant of 3 above, but I'm not sure if it's any faster. And I don't know if it's doable without relying on the implementation details.
5. Use regular `dict` in the data structure, rewriting all the code there to first check if the element is in the dictionary and adding it if it's not. Not good.

Comment: the "rewriting" would just use the `dict.setdefault` method... No big deal

Comment: @JBernardo Are you talking about option 4? All I know about `defaultdict` is that it overrides `__getitem__` to add an element if needed. Maybe it does that using `setdefault` method, maybe it implements the same logic directly without ever calling `setdefault`. Without relying on implementation details, I can't assume anything, can I?

Comment: He is referring to your option #5. Just use your data.setdefault() in your code in replacement of defaultdict

Comment: I think you should be able to get away with just calling `dict` on teh `defaultdict` to dictify it

Comment: @Pyson: ah you're right, it makes sense. But that's the argument in favor of never using `defaultdict`, isn't it? (Not that I disagree, just want to understand the logic.)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget the size of the data structure is over 1 GB, so copying all the data (as would happen if I call `dict`) is too expensive.

Comment: Well, defaultdict is faster in most cases...

Comment: @Pyson: Why? `dict.setdefault` is implemented in C, and it does precisely what `defaultdict.__getitem__` does. Shouldn't it be equally fast?

Comment: You would think so, huh?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) docs say for `default_factory`:

> If the default_factory attribute is None, this raises a KeyError
>   exception with the key as argument.

What if you just set your defaultdict's default_factory to `None`? E.g.,

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['a'] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 1})
>>> d.default_factory = None
>>> d['b'] += 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'b'
>>>
```

Not sure if this is the best approach, but seems to work.

Comment: Who knew that the solution I proposed was already implemented as a feature of `defaultdict`?  Great find.  (+1)

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. I hope it's safe to change `default_factory` for an existing `defaultdict` object (I don't see why not).

Comment: @max -- The documentation specifically says that `default_factory` is a **writable** attribute, so it should be safe.

Comment: @max: Use the source: [`defdictobject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d0686d90f55/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1253), [`defdict_members`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d0686d90f55/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1375) (name, type, offset, flags, doc; `flags==0` means it's writable), [`defdict_missing`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d0686d90f55/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1262).

Answer (score 4):

Once you have finished populating your defaultdict, you can simply create a regular dict from it:

```
my_dict = dict(my_default_dict)
```

If the default dict is a recursive default dict, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921635/832230) which has a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that holds a reference to your dict and prevent **setitem**()

```
from collections import Mapping

class MyDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d;

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.d[k]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__iter__()

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if k not in self.d.keys():
            raise KeyError
        else:
            self.d[k] = v
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be super slow, given that it uses pure python for critical methods?

Comment: For the getitem method?  Not sure the performance overhead with that vs. defaultdict's

Comment: Either way, I think Neal's solution is best for your problem