# finding key in dict using try except

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch, except

My function is:

```
def searchstock():  
dictionary=calcreturn(dictionize(tickers(openfile()),pairslist()))
inp=raw_input("What is the stock ticker? ")
while True:
    try:
        dictionary[inp]
        break
    except KeyError: 
        print("Ticker not found. Please input again ")

print(inp, dictionary[inp])
```

the try/except doesnt work. I'm trying to see if a user input is in the dictionary keys and then return the key and respective value

If imp is not in the dictionary, why would this be an infinite loop?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary

Comment: It needs to be using try/exept, not if/else

Comment: you should not modify your original question ... as now it looks like every answer just copied and pasted what you had (which is not the case)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the loop?

Answer (score 2):

just

```
inp=raw_input("What is the stock ticker? ")
try:
   dictionary[inp]
   break; #exit loop
except KeyError:
   print "Nope!"
```

you will also need to break out of your `while True` loop

also if you are using py2x you will want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: NameError: name 'BIG' is not defined

Comment: thats a different problem caused by using `input` in python 2.x instead of `raw_input`

Comment: The problem with the code is NameError: name 'BIG' is not defined

Comment: @user2356391 when you do a normal 'input' in Python, if you enter a value like 'BIG' it is considered to be an object name. Here it is not defined. 
So as suggested by JoranBeasley change it to raw_input() and your code will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

listkeys in your code is a list and not a dictionary. Finding an element in a list will not give you a KeyError.

If you are using lists,

```
item in list_name
```

will give either True or False.

Also modify your input to raw_input() so that it considers strings as strings and not as object names.

Try using something like the following:

```
try:
    dictionary_name[key]
except KeyError:
    #do something
    print "Key Error"
```

Comment: I changed it to get rid of the list and just search if the input is in the dictionary

Comment: i still get NameError: name 'BIG' is not defined when i input "BIG" for input (and BIG is int he keys of the dictionary)

Comment: @user2356391 when you do a normal 'input' in Python, if you enter a value like 'BIG' it is considered to be an object name. Here it is not defined. So as suggested by JoranBeasley change it to raw_input() and your code will work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but to check if a value is a dictionary key, it's very simple:

```
'key' in dictionary
```

which returns `True` or `False`.

Additionally, you could even do something like:

```
mydictionary.get('key', 'Key not in dictionary')
```

And if the key isn't in the dictionary, you'll get the string `"Key not in dictionary"`, otherwise you'll get the actual value marked by `'key'`.

Comment: There could be a possible bug here if the dictionary contains 'Key not in dictionary' itself as a value.

Comment: This was just an example.  And since we're talking about stock tickers, I highly doubt there would be a stock ticker 
`"Key not in dictionary"` in that dictionary.