# Python If & Dictionary Usage in Address book program

Tags: python

I am making a small address book program as practice, do you know what's wrong with my code when I tried to add new entry?

Also, how can I make it go back to choose 1-4 instead of keep in the same sub condition like error 2?

Thanks so much!

```
print('|-----Welcome to Q\'s Addrss Book-------|')
print('|--------------------------------------|')
print('|Please choice from the following:-----|')
print('|----------1: Find   Contacts----------|')
print('|----------2: Add    Contacts----------|')
print('|----------3: Delete Contacts----------|')
print('|----------4: Quit Address Book--------|')

i = int(input('Can I help you? :'))
address = {'ray':1234,'simon':2345,'alen':8888}
while 1:
    if i == 1:
        x=input('What\'s his/her name?')
        print(address[x])

    if i == 2:
        x = (input('New Contact name?'))
        if address[x] is not None:
            z = str(input('Contact'+x+' with phone number: '+str(address[x])+ ' address already existed, do you want to override?(Yes/No)'))
            if z == 'yes':
                address[x] = input('New number?')
            elif z == 'no':
                break
            else:
                print('Please choose yes or no')
        else:
            address[x] = input('New number?')

    if i == 3:
        z = input('Who you want to delete:')
        if address[z] is not None:
            del address[z]
        else:
            print('Contact not existed!')

    if i == 4:
        break
```

Error1:

```
>>> 
|-----Welcome to Q's Addrss Book-------|
|--------------------------------------|
|Please choice from the following:-----|
|----------1: Find   Contacts----------|
|----------2: Add    Contacts----------|
|----------3: Delete Contacts----------|
|----------4: Quit Address Book--------|
Can I help you?:2
New Contact name?q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/1.py", line 18, in <module>
    if address[x] is not None:
KeyError: 'q'
>>>
```

Error 2: keep looping in a sub if condition:

```
>>> 
|-----Welcome to Q's Addrss Book-------|
|--------------------------------------|
|Please choice from the following:-----|
|----------1: Find   Contacts----------|
|----------2: Add    Contacts----------|
|----------3: Delete Contacts----------|
|----------4: Quit Address Book--------|
Can I help you?:1
What's his/her name?ray
1234
What's his/her name?
>>>
```

Ok, thanks for all your guys, I have made it work, here is the correct code:

```
print('|-----Welcome to Q\'s Addrss Book-------|')
print('|--------------------------------------|')
print('|Please choice from the following:-----|')
print('|----------1: Find   Contacts----------|')
print('|----------2: Add    Contacts----------|')
print('|----------3: Delete Contacts----------|')
print('|----------4: Quit Address Book--------|')


address = {'ray':123456789,'simon':222222222,'alen':88888888}
while 1:
    i = int(input('Can I help you?'))
    if i == 1:
        x=input('What\'s his/her name?')
        if x in address:
            print(address[x])
        else:
            print('Contact does not exist!')

    if i == 2:
        x = (input('New Contact name?'))
        if x in address:
            z = str(input('Contact'+x+' with phone number: '+str(address[x])+ ' address already existed, do you want to override?(Yes/No)'))
            if z == 'yes':
                address[x] = input('New number?')
            elif z == 'no':
                continue
            else:
                print('Please choose yes or no')
        else:
            address[x] = input('New number?')

    if i == 3:
        z = input('Who you want to delete:')
        if z  in address:
            del address[z]
        else:
            print('Contact does not exist!')

    if i == 4:
        break
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary Is a better way to check if a name exists instead of `if address[x] is not None:`

Comment: It's not just a better way, it's the *only* way. `if address[x] is not None:` doesn't work. It throws a KeyError whenever `x` is not in the `address` dictionary.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Well, not the only way.  The best way.  However you could also use a default dict and use OPs method.  Or you could use the dict.get method with None being the default.  But yes, I understand what you're saying and agree that using `in` should be the only way used.

Comment: For the second error you just need to put `i = int(input('Can I help you? :'))` inside the while loop.  Or put a condition that will break if i==1 and the input is blank or something.

Comment: thanks so much Stack of Pancakes!!! it worked!!! sorry for my dump question :)

Answer (score 0):

'Stack of Pancakes' has answered the second part of your question already (see comments above)

When you're trying to check whether the contact already exists, it's important to clarify that `address[x] == None` will never return `True` if `x` is not a key in the dictionary. If Python can't find a key in a dictionary, it doesn't return `None`, but throws a `KeyError` exception. Python uses exceptions far more liberally than some other languages - [this article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/) covers them in a bit more detail, and you can also read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

The 'pythonic' way to work with them is more like this:

```
if x not in address:
    ....
```

And then in your block for deleting contacts:

```
try:
    del address[z]
except KeyError:
    print('Contact does not exist!')
```

Here the code 'tries' to delete the key from the dictionary. If the key never existed in the first place, a `KeyError` exception is raised on the second line of this code. But we have an `except` clause specifically designed to catch `KeyError` exceptions, so you won't see a stack trace. Execution moves to the print function on the final line.

Comment: HI Stephan, I tried adding " except KeyError:" that one, but it said invalid sytax?

Comment: Did the error give any more detail than that? You could check indentation first - make sure it matches that above and in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). If not that, the syntax error is probably in the blocks themselves - either on the line `del address[z]` or in the print function. If you keep getting the error then make an edit to the question and paste your code in there.