# Updating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created three dictionaries-dict1, dict2, and dict2.  I want to update dict1 with dict2 first, and resulting dictionary with dict3. I am not sure why they are not adding up.

```
def wordcount_directory(directory):
    dict = {}
    filelist=[os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    dicts=[wordcount_file(file) for file in filelist]
    dict1=dicts[0]
    dict2=dicts[1]
    dict3=dicts[2]
    for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
        if k in dict2.keys():
            dict1[k]+=1
        else:
            dict1[k]=v
    for k1,v1 in dict1.iteritems():
        if k1 in dict3.keys():
            dict1[k1]+=1
        else:
            dict1[k1]=v1
return dict1

print wordcount_directory("C:\\Users\\Phil2040\\Desktop\\Word_count")
```

Comment: ou need to elaborate on `I am not sure why they are not adding up.`. Post some sample values for `dict1`, `dict2` and `dict3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding you question right, but are you trying to add all the values from each of the dictionaries together into one final dictionary? If so:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 5, 'c': 1, 'd': 9}
dict3 = {'d': 1, 'e': 7}

def add_dict(to_dict, from_dict):
    for key, value in from_dict.iteritems():
        to_dict[key] = to_dict.get(key, 0) + value

result = dict(dict1)
add_dict(result, dict2)
add_dict(result, dict3)
print result
```

This yields: `{'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 7, 'e': 7, 'd': 10}`

It would be really helpful to post what the expected outcome should be for your question.

**EDIT:**

*For an arbitrary amount of dictionaries:*

```
result = dict(dicts[0])
for dict_sum in dicts[1:]:
    add_dict(result, dict_sum)
print(result)
```

*If you really want to fix the code from your original question in the format it is in:*

1. You are using `dict1[k]+=1` when you should be performing `dict1[k]+=dict2.get(k, 0)`.
2. The introduction of `get` removes the need to check for its existence with an if statement.
3. You need to iterate though `dict2` and `dict3` to introduce new keys from them into `dict1`
4. (not really a problem, but worth mentioning) In the if statement to check if the key is in the dictionary, it is recommended to simply the operation to `if k in dict2:` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602964/1279231) for more details)

*With the amazing built-in library found by @DisplacedAussie, the answer can be simplified even further:*

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2) + Counter(dict3))
```

The result yields: `Counter({'d': 10, 'b': 7, 'e': 7, 'c': 4, 'a': 1})`

The `Counter` object is a sub-class of `dict`, so it can be used in the same way as a standard `dict`.

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  How can I include this function to my original function (wordcount_directory)?

Comment: It's even easier with collections.Counter: from collections import Counter Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2) + Counter(dict3)

Comment: @Phil2014 Place the function I made in your file, and the last four lines in your existing function (replacing print with return). In my answer I made a copy of `dict1` into a new variable `result` so `dict1` was not modified. If you do not mind `dict` being altered, you can apply all the operations directly to `dict1`.

Comment: @DisplacedAussie That is hilarious. I am assured every day that Python has a library for *everything*. Thanks for sharing! That is a neat library.

Comment: @PM2Ring No, I really like the library. If find it funny because it would substitute the function I made and make this solution into one line.

Comment: @jakebird451 Why mine was not working?  My idea was updating dict1 with dict2 first and resulting dict1 with dict3.

Comment: While I prefer the .get(...,0) approach to my use of sets ... and I did upvote this answer; I think that having the function modify the *second* argument is counter-intuitive.  Conventionally if a function mutates one of its arguments then those should be the leftmost in the parameter list.  This matches the intuitions of many programmers regarding "L-values" and "R-values" ... in other words it looks more like an assignment.

Comment: @JimDennis Yea, I had that vibe as I was writing the answer. I guess I went with the unix ordering of from, to. But this isn't unix land. I'll change it to make more sense. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Phil2014 I added a couple of notes in my answer to why your original code did not work.

Comment: @ Jakebird.  I hard coded dict1, dict2, dict3.  If have a lot of dictionaries, how can I automate it?

Comment: This is great. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, here a simple function that might help:

```
def dictsum(dict1, dict2):
   '''Modify dict1 to accumulate new sums from dict2
   '''
   k1 = set(dict1.keys())
   k2 = set(dict2.keys())
   for i in k1 & k2:
       dict1[i] += dict2[i]
   for i in k2 - k1:
       dict1[i] = dict2[i]
   return None
```

... for the intersection update each by adding the second value to the existing one; then for the difference add those key/value pairs.

With that defined you'd simple call:

```
dictsum(dict1, dict2)
dictsum(dict1, dict3)
```

... and be happy.

(I will note that functions modify the contents of dictionaries in this fashion are not all that common.  I'm returning `None` explicitly to follow the convention established by the `list.sort()` method ... functions which modify the contents of a container, in Python, do not normally return copies of the container).

Comment: Nice work, Jim. I probably wouldn't do the explicit `return None`, but it's certainly worth mentioning that functions that do in-place modifications of containers conventionally return `None` in Python.

Comment: Yes, it would be implicitly the same ... that's really just a hint to those reading and maintaining the code.

Comment: I'll confess that my use of sets here is slightly gratuitous.  .iteritems() with .get(..., 0) is more space efficient.  However, I think it's a useful example to remind readers that set operations (intersection and difference) are frequently useful with dictionary keys.

Comment: Good point; `.get(..., 0)` is certainly better than extracting the key list and building a set from it, both space-wise & time-wise. OTOH, it'd be interesting to compare timings, since the set intersection & difference operations are rather efficient, IIRC, so the above algorithm might end up being faster than a `get`-based one.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are iterating on the wrong dictionary. You want to iterate over `dict2` and update `dict1` with matching keys or add non-matching keys to `dict1`.

If so, here's how you need to update the for loops:

```
for k,v in dict2.iteritems():     # Iterate over dict2
    if k in dict1.keys():         
        dict1[k]+=1               # Update dict1 for matching keys 
    else:
        dict1[k]=v                # Add non-matching keys to dict1
for k1,v1 in dict3.iteritems():   # Iterate over dict3
    if k1 in dict1.keys():
        dict1[k1]+=1              # Update dict1 for matching keys
    else:
        dict1[k1]=v1              # Add non-matching keys to dict1
```

Comment: @ Ronak Gandhi.  I double checked with other example too (iteration is correct).

Comment: You need to elaborate on `I am not sure why they are not adding up.`. Post some sample values for `dict1, dict2 and dict3`.

Comment: @ Ronak Gandhi. jakebird451 has example.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `wordcount_file(file)` returns a dict of the words found in `file`, with each key being a word and the associated value being the count for that word. If so, your updating algorithm is wrong. You should do something like this:

```
keys1 = dict1.keys()
for k,v in dict2.iteritems():
    if k in keys1:
        dict1[k] += v
    else:
        dict1[k] = v
```

If there's a lot of data in these `dict`s you can make the key lookup faster by storing the keys in a set:

`keys1 = set(dict1.keys())`

You should probably put that code into a function, so you don't need to duplicate the code when you want to update `dict1` with the data in `dict3`.

You should take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), a subclass of `dict` that supports counting; using `Counter`s would simplify this task considerably. But if this is an assignment (or you're using Python 2.6 or older) you may not be able to use `Counter`s.

Comment: @ PM 2Ring. Yes.dicts is list of three dictionaries and I subsetted it into three. I thought it should work.

Comment: @Phil2014: Yes, that part of your code is fine.; it's just your updating code that's wrong. Firstly, your `for` loops are iterating over the wrong `dict`, so in the first loop it will not pick up any keys that are in `dict2` if they aren't also present in `dict1`. Secondly, the  `dict1[k]+=1` means that you're not adding the value from `dict2` to the  value in `dict1`: you're only adding 1 to the count in `dict1`, no matter what the count is in `dict2` for that key.