# Python - If value in dictionary then

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

Here's my code

```
    if "value" not in dictionary():
        do something
    else:
        do something else
```

I get the error 'TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

I've tried changing the first line to

```
    if dictionary["value"]:
```

But get a different error. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: This should help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary

Comment: Why are you calling the dictionary?

Comment: remove the `()` after the `not in dictionary`

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `dictionary` is in fact a `dict()` composed of key-values then it would be

```
if 'value' not in dictionary:
    ...etc
```

The error is essentially telling you that you are erroneously attempting to call a non-callable object as if it were a method/function.

If you are not particularly interested in whether or not a value exists you may use a method I am personally a fan of:

```
some_value = dictionary.get('value', 'valueIfNotPresent')
do_something(some_value)
```

The above allows you to provide a sentinel value (which is provided when the key does not exist).  This can help with branch elimination (e.g. not having to if/else it, just allowing your code to act upon the sentinel) or at least reduce logic in checking for the existence of a key (unless the absence of a key is important).

Both are quite readable however and your mileage may vary.

EDIT:

@user1857805 is correct, if you are attempting to find out if a value is in a dictionary then the above (while still good and valid to know) is not enough.  You will need to get the `.values()` as a list from the dictionary; however, as a dictionary may contain dictionaries you will need to recurse the dictionary to find all of the possibly stored values.

Comment: no worries, we've all been there a million times over.  don't forget to mark the answers when appropriate :)

Comment: @XJ220, if you are happy with an answer, you are supposed to use a 'green tick', not just an upvote...

Comment: Good use of the dictionary `get` method.

Answer (score 3):

try using the following:

```
if 'value' not in dictionary.values():
    do something
else:
    do something else.
```