# Pythonic way to check if element in a list contains in key dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a mapping keywords like this.

```
categories_mapping = {
        'comics': 'Comic Books',
        'cartoons': 'Comic Books',
        'manga': 'Comic Books',
        'video and computer games': 'Video Games',
        'role playing games': 'Video Games',
        'immigration': 'Immigration',
        'police': 'Police',
        'environmental': 'Environment',
        'celebrity fan and gossip': 'Celebrity',
        'space and technology': 'NASA / Space',
        'movies and tv': 'TV and Movies',
        'elections': 'Elections',
        'referendums': 'Elections',
        'sex': 'Sex',
        'music': 'Music',
        'technology and computing': 'Technology'}
```

and a list like this.

```
labels = ['technology and computing', 'arts and technology']
```

I want to return the value of the dictionary if any words in the list is in the key of the dictionary.

This is what I've come up with but I think that's not very pythonic.

```
cats = []
for k,v in categories_mapping.items():
    for l in labels:
        if k in l:
            cats.append(v)
return cats
```

The result I want is `['Technology']`

Any better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is `labels` here?

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: You might want to consider using frozensets for your dictionary keys. It will make the lookup faster, and better represent the data.

Comment: Do you mean `for l in labels: if k in l` or do you just mean `if k in labels` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: Are you looking for any _single word_, e.g. `movies` to find the key `'movies and tv'`, or are you looking for exact matches?

Comment: It cannot be exact match. It can be partially match.

Comment: Okay. Should it ignore case? Is it looking for exact matches of single words (separated by whitespace)? Should it match parts of words? Should it match similar words?

Comment: Your edit just invalidated every single answer. At this point, I'd recommend rolling back your edits, accepting an answer that was appropriate to the original question, and asking a new question that includes all relevant information.

Comment: Just rolled back my question and I'll create a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `intersection` of your labels and dictionary keys:

```
cats = [categories_mapping[key] for key in set(labels).intersection(categories_mapping)]
```

Update for partial match:

```
cats = [categories_mapping[key] for key in categories_mapping if any(label.lower() in key.lower() for label in labels)]
```

Comment: Sorry I've just updated my answer would this work with partial match?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [categories_mapping[l] for l in labels if l in categories_mapping]
['Technology']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the outer loop:

```
for l in labels:
    if l in categories_mapping:
        cats.append(categories_mapping[l])
```

Or as a list comp:

```
 cats = [v for k, v in categories_mapping if k in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> categories_mapping = {
        'comics': 'Comic Books',
        'cartoons': 'Comic Books',
        'manga': 'Comic Books',
        'video and computer games': 'Video Games',
        'role playing games': 'Video Games',
        'immigration': 'Immigration',
        'police': 'Police',
        'environmental': 'Environment',
        'celebrity fan and gossip': 'Celebrity',
        'space and technology': 'NASA / Space',
        'movies and tv': 'TV and Movies',
        'elections': 'Elections',
        'referendums': 'Elections',
        'sex': 'Sex',
        'music': 'Music',
        'technology and computing': 'Technology'}
>>> labels = ['technology and computing', 'arts and technology']
>>> cats = []
>>> for l in labels:
    if l in categories_mapping:
        cats.append(categories_mapping[l])
>>> cats
['Technology']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cats = [v for k, v in categories_mapping.items() if k in labels]
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide an explanation for your solution.