# How to check if a key-value pair is present in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Is there a smart pythonic way to check if there is an item (key,value) in a dict?

```
a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
b={'a':1}
c={'a':2}

b in a:
--> True
c in a:
--> False
```

Comment: why not use `.get()` ?

Comment: @letsc: please post it as answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the short circuiting property of `and`. In this way if the left hand is false, then you will not get a `KeyError` while checking for the value.

```
>>> a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> key,value = 'c',3                # Key and value present
>>> key in a and value == a[key]
True
>>> key,value = 'b',3                # value absent
>>> key in a and value == a[key]
False
>>> key,value = 'z',3                # Key absent
>>> key in a and value == a[key]
False
```

Comment: This performs two dictionary lookups, when one is sufficent.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus This is better in the worst case, if not in the best case.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why is this better than `.get()`?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus,  because it is faster

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: It saves you the trouble of using an explicit sentinel value when `None` is a valid dict value. Also, looking up `get` is a dict lookup anyway.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, you will have a problem if `b={'a':None}` etc. unless you use `a.get(k, object())` to ensure no false equalities.

Comment: @Padraic: sounds surpising, I won't believe it until I measure it myself.

Comment: @user: `get` is one dictionary lookup, while this answer suggests two. I can't imagine how two can be faster than one.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Using `get` takes an extra lookup just to find the `get` method, before you even call it.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, I have timed it before for a similar question, it is definitely faster

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus A related post on the speed of `get`. [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37968524)

Comment: is it any better than operator <= mentioned in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34273667/3936509

Answer (score 11):

You can check a tuple of the key, value against the dictionary's `.items()`.

```
test = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(('a', 1) in test.items())
>>> True
```

Comment: This is really slow, since it builds a list of items and does a linear search through the list.

Comment: @user2357112 True. If it's a performance critical part of the program, I would go with Bhargav Rao's answer, but I would argue that this is more readable.

Comment: Would `iteritems()` be faster? I mean, still linear search, but memory wise, it's a generator.

Comment: 22 seconds before me :/

Comment: @cricket_007 I have no idea. Python 3 doesn't have `iteritems()`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, huh. I thought it didn't. I don't use Python 2.

Comment: When one option is O(n), the other option is O(1), and both options are 1-liners, any readability gain simply isn't worth it.

Answer (score 10):

You've tagged this 2.7, as opposed to 2.x, so you can check whether the tuple is in the dict's `viewitems`:

```
(key, value) in d.viewitems()
```

Under the hood, this basically does `key in d and d[key] == value`.

In Python 3, `viewitems` is just `items`, but don't use `items` in Python 2! That'll build a list and do a linear search, taking O(n) time and space to do what should be a quick O(1) check.

Comment: Isn't `iteritems` in Python2.x considered `items` in Python3? Docs say `viewitems` is a dynamic view object.

Comment: @cricket_007: No, `iteritems` in Python 2 has no Python 3 equivalent. Python 3's `items` is a dynamic view object like Python 2.7's `viewitems`.

Comment: I voted up because this is python 2.7. However just a warning for python 2.6, this does not work.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> b = {'a': 1}
>>> c = {'a': 2}
```

First here is a way that works for Python2 *and* Python3

```
>>> all(k in a and a[k] == b[k] for k in b)
True
>>> all(k in a and a[k] == c[k] for k in c)
False
```

In Python3 you can also use

```
>>> b.items() <= a.items()
True
>>> c.items() <= a.items()
False
```

For Python2, the equivalent is

```
>>> b.viewitems() <= a.viewitems()
True
>>> c.viewitems() <= a.viewitems()
False
```

Comment: The `if k in a` check means that the `all` check will report `{'d': 4}` as a subdict of `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Converting my comment into an answer :

Use the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method which is already provided as an inbuilt method (and I assume is the most pythonic)

```
>>> dict = {'Name': 'Anakin', 'Age': 27}
>>> dict.get('Age')
27
>>> dict.get('Gender', 'None')
'None'
>>>
```

As per the docs -

> get(key, default) - 
>    Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
>   If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method
>   never raises a KeyError.

Answer (score 1):

Using `get`:

```py
# this doesn't work if `None` is a possible value in the dict
# but in that case you can use a different sentinel value
# as the default
a.get('a') == 1
```

Using `get` with a unique sentinel:

```py
# With a custom sentinel as the default value, `None` 
# should only be returned if `None` is the actual
# value in the key/value pair.
_unique_sentinel = object()
a.get('a', _unique_sentinel) == None
```

Using try/except:

```py
# more verbose than using simple `get` without sentinel value
# but more foolproof also
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
try:
    has_item = a['a'] == 1
except KeyError:
    has_item = False

print(has_item)
```

Other answers suggesting `items` in Python3 and `viewitems` in Python 2.7 are easier to read and more idiomatic, but the suggestions in this answer will work in both Python versions without any compatibility code and will still run in constant time. Pick your poison.

Answer (score 0):

```
   a.get('a') == 1
=> True
   a.get('a') == 2
=> False
```

if `None` is valid item:

```
{'x': None}.get('x', object()) is None
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.get` is usually the best way to check if a key value pair exist.

```
if my_dict.get('some_key'):
  # Do something
```

There is one caveat, if the key exists but is falsy then it will fail the test which may not be what you want. Keep in mind this is rarely the case. Now the inverse is a more frequent problem. That is using `in` to test the presence of a key. I have found this problem frequently when reading csv files.

Example

```
# csv looks something like this:
a,b
1,1
1,

# now the code
import csv
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as fh:
  reader = csv.DictReader(fh) # reader is basically a list of dicts
  for row_d in reader:
    if 'b' in row_d:
      # On the second iteration of this loop, b maps to the empty string but
      # passes this condition statement, most of the time you won't want 
      # this. Using .get would be better for most things here.
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.x 
use **`if key in dict`**

See the sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
b={'a':1}
c={'a':2}
mylist = [a, b, c]
for obj in mylist:
    if 'b' in obj:
        print(obj['b'])


Output: 2
```