# What can I do for my program not to throw a KeyError for a Header not existing in a .fits file?

Tags: python, keyerror, astropy, fits, pyfits

I am making a program that searches the computer for .fts and .fits files in which it opens the file and retrieves info that corresponds to a specific keyword in the header and renames the file to that keyword.

I am having a problem where i keep receiving a KeyError becasue a header keyword I am searching for is not found in the file. Is there a way around this? I want to be able to search various keywords and do something even if that key word does not exist in the file.

Here is code:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import os

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
if i.endswith(".fits") or i.endswith(".fts"): 

    hdulist = fits.open(i)

    DATEOBS_header = hdulist[0].header['DATE-OBS'] 
    EXPTIME_header = int(round(hdulist[0].header['EXPTIME']))
    CCDTEMP_header = int(round(hdulist[0].header['CCD-TEMP']))
    XBINNING_header = hdulist[0].header['XBINNING']
    FILTER_header = hdulist[0].header['FILTER']
    IMAGETYP_header = hdulist[0].header['IMAGETYP']
    OBJECT_header = hdulist[0].header['OBJECT']

    DATEandTIME = DATEOBS_header[0:]
    YEAR = DATEandTIME[0:4]
    MONTH = DATEandTIME[5:7]
    DAY = DATEandTIME[8:10]

    #TIME = DATEOBS_header[11:] 
    HOUR = DATEandTIME[11:13]
    MINUTE = DATEandTIME[14:16]
    SECONDS = DATEandTIME[17:]

    DATE = str(YEAR) + str(MONTH) + str(DAY) + 'at' + str(HOUR) + str(MINUTE) + str(SECONDS) 

    if IMAGETYP_header == 'Light Frame':
        newname = str(OBJECT_header) + '_' + str(DATE) + '_' + str(CCDTEMP_header) + 'temp_' + str(XBINNING_header) + 'bin_' + str(EXPTIME_header) + 'exptime_' + str(FILTER_header) + '.fits'

    if IMAGETYP_header == 'Dark Frame':
        newname = 'Dark_' + str(DATE) + 'at' + str(TIME) + '_' + str(CCDTEMP_header) + 'temp_' + str(XBINNING_header) + 'bin_' + str(EXPTIME_header) + 'exptime' + '.fits'

    if IMAGETYP_header == 'Flat Field':
        newname = 'Flat_' + str(DATE) + 'at' + str(TIME) + '_' + str(CCDTEMP_header) + 'temp_' + str(XBINNING_header) + 'bin_' + str(EXPTIME_header) + 'exptime_' + str(FILTER_header) + '.fits'

    prevname = i
    os.rename(prevname, newname)

    hdulist.close()

    continue
else:
    continue
```

This is the Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "glo1.py", line 9, in <module>
    DATEOBS_header = hdulist[0].header['DATE-OBS'] 
  File "/home/luisgeesb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 151, in __getitem__
card = self._cards[self._cardindex(key)]
  File "/home/luisgeesb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 1723, in _cardindex
raise KeyError("Keyword %r not found." % keyword)
KeyError: "Keyword 'DATE-OBS' not found."
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to perform some exception handling

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: You can also use a default value using something like `DATEOBS_header = hdulist[0].header.get('DATE-OBS', some_default_value)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: Also similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey

Comment: Technically dict-related questions are not duplicates of this question, because the FITS `Header` object is not a `dict` (see http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/headers.html#header). Behavior-wise it is as close to `dict` as possible so most answers related to `dict` would apply, but this isn't necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent these kinds of exceptions from stopping your program, you can either catch them, like this:

```
try:
    DATEOBS_header = hdulist[0].header['DATE-OBS']
except KeyError:
    DATEOBS_header = None
```

Or, use the `.get()` method of dictionaries, which checks if a key exists and if it doesn't returns a default value, instead of raising an exception. The default value returned is `None`.

If you do this, you will also need to set some sensible defaults, or catch those cases where you are casting the values (since you cannot cast `None`).

Finally, whenever you are reading from files - you should always assume the data is malformed/junk and do a bit of defensive programming. In your code, you are assuming that the values returned for `CCDTEMP` is a number, but what if the file is corrupted or has a blank? Your application doesn't handle this case.

Here is some code that attempts to catch as many errors as possible:

```
DATEOBS_header = hdulist[0].header.get('DATE-OBS') 
XBINNING_header = hdulist[0].header.get('XBINNING')
FILTER_header = hdulist[0].header.get('FILTER')
IMAGETYP_header = hdulist[0].header.get('IMAGETYP')
OBJECT_header = hdulist[0].header.get('OBJECT')

# For these two, you need to either set a default
# Here I am setting the default to 0,           ------------v
EXPTIME_header = int(round(hdulist[0].header.get('EXPTIME', 0)))


# Or you need to check for a value :
ccdtemp_value = hdulist[0].header.get('CCD-TEMP')
try:
   ccdtemp_value = int(round(ccdtemp_value))
except ValueError:
   # This means, the value was either None (header does not exist)
   # or it was something that can't be converted to a number
   # since it cannot be converted to a number, we do not know
   # if the value is None or something like an empty string,
   # so we explicitly set the value to None
   ccdtemp_value = None
CCDTEMP_header = ccdtemp_value
```

Comment: when setting a default value, will it return the default value if the keyword is not found ? For example, in the code above where it says 'ccdtemp_value = hdulist[0].header.get('CCD-TEMP')' if CCD-TEMP is not found it will return 0 ?

Comment: The default return value if the key is not found is `None`, so if you want it to be zero, you need to pass it in, like this: `ccdtemp_value = hdulist[0].header.get('CCD-TEMP', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `hdulist[0].header` gives you a `dict` instance, you can do something like

```
DATEOBS_header = hdulist[0].header.get('DATE-OBS')
```

Which would return a `None` if the key `'DATE-OBS'` does not exist.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get for more details.

Comment: `hdulist[0].header` is not a dict or dict subclass, but it acts similar.