# Convert php !array_key_exists to python

Tags: php, python

I made a code in php for data cleaning. Now I am trying to write the same code in python since python speed seems to be faster than php.

I have problem in one part of code, as I am not understanding, how should I write this code in python.

This is my php code. How can I write this part in python?

```
if(!array_key_exists("specialities",$d['data']))
{
   continue;
}
```

I tried the following, but its not working:-

```
if not "specialities" in d['data']:
   continue
```

and

```
if "specialities" not in d['data']:
   continue
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

This is the sample data:

```
"data" : {
        "website" : "something",
        "city" : "Bangalore",
        "specialties" : null,
        "description" : "",
        "zip" : "560029",
        "companyName" : "XYZ Company",
        "street1" : "SG Palya",
        "state" : "Karnataka",
    }
```

This data is being retrieved from mongodb in json format.

Comment: Can you add the format of the array you want to check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: `d` is of what type ?

Comment: `if not "specialities" in d['data'].keys()`

Comment: @jurruh i added the data format

Comment: @cb0 `d` is an array

Comment: Define "is not working". What's it (not) doing?

Comment: @deceze I want the company names for domains. So if the array key `specialities` does not exist, return the control to beginning of the loop..

Comment: And it's… `continue`ing when it shouldn't? Or the other way around?

Comment: Sorry guys...@manuel is correct. Its a typo mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the error is only a typo in the data?

Check: **specialities** != **specialties**

Your suggested solution should work:

```
if "specialties" not in d['data']:
    continue
```