# Conditional checks for JSON key-value pairs being ignored

Tags: python, json, geojson

I am building a point feature class from a web call that returns JSON.  The JSON is a bit sketchy in that sometimes keys do not exist in the record.  I am trying to do this, once I have a valid JSON object:

```
#requests stuff above this

for i in jsonObj:
    try:
        if i['properties']['country']:
            country = i['properties']['country']
        else:
            country = 'UNK'
            print('Country name not found, using {}'.format(country))
    except KeyError, e:
        print('Key error: reason: {}'.format(str(e)))
        pass

#then do all the arcpy FC creation stuff
```

The result is a whole bunch of key errors with "reason: 'country'" and instead of building those rows with the generic 'country' value of 'UNK', it will simply ignore them and build the feature class, leaving out those points.

I have taken out the `try` and left it as a conditional check, but it fails at the first row that lacks a 'country' key.

In summary, I'm just trying to check if a key-value pair exists; if it doesn't, assign a generic value of `'UNK'` to the `country` variable.

It seems like part of the problem might be that `if i['properties']['countries']` is checking for a value, but not the existence of the key itself?  How might I more efficiently check for the existence of the key?

---

I have read [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary) and have modified my code to both of these, and neither yield the expected outcome:

```
for i in jsonObj:
    try:
        # get coordinates first
        if i['geometry']['coordinates']:
            ycoord = float(i['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
            xcoord = float(i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
            if i['properties']['city'] in i:
                city = i['properties']['city']
            else:
                city = 'UNK'

            if i['properties']['country'] in i:
                country = i['properties']['country']
            else:
                country = 'UNK'
```

and

```
for i in jsonObj:
    try:
        # get coordinates first
        if i['geometry']['coordinates']:
            ycoord = float(i['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
            xcoord = float(i['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
            if 'city' in i:
                city = i['properties']['city']
            else:
                city = 'UNK'

            if 'country' in i:
                country = i['properties']['country']
            else:
                country = 'UNK'
```

I do have the 'properties' key in every record/dictionary, but whether I have a 'country' key is not guaranteed. Some rows in the json response have it, some rows don't

Comment: you may try `if 'properties' in i:, not `if 'country' in i:`.

Comment: do you have the `properties` key in each dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I do have the 'properties' key in every record/dictionary, but whether I have a 'country' key is not guaranteed.  Some rows in the json response have it, some rows don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last try:

```
if 'country' in i:
    country = i['properties']['country']
else:
    country = 'UNK'
```

was close, but you're managing a dict of dicts, and `'country'` has better chance to be a key of the sub-dict, so the fix would be:

```
if 'country' in i['properties']:
    country = i['properties']['country']
else:
    country = 'UNK'
```

or even better & shorter using `get` with a default value (I recommend that last one over the quickfix):

```
country = i['properties'].get('country','UNK')
```

Comment: Moving to the .get() method was going to be my next mod to this script, so thank you for the clarity on it.  So with that, I could eliminate even doing an if-else check at all, yes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't fully understand json implementation.

`x = i['geometry']['coordinates']` is basically `y = i['geometry']; x = y['coordinates']`, so you need safety check for each layer, becaue `i['geometry']` not only will throw exception when `'geometry'` field is not found but also the returned object must also implement `[]` for `['coordinates']` to work (so in this case it must be another `json object`, and not `string`,`bool`,`None` etc.)

I also believe your json object is implemented using python dictionary, so you can check if certain field, e.g. `'geometry'` exists using `x.get('geometry')`, which will return either its value or `None` object. You can also use `city = x.get('city', 'UKN')` to set default value (`json object`, `string`, `bool`, `None` etc.) if it was not found in dict (python `dict.get` method implements default handler).

So in the end you should have something like this:

```
geo = i.get('geometry')
if not geo: return

coords = geo.get('coordinates')
if not coords: return
xcoord, ycoord = float(coords[0]), float(coords[1])

props = i.get('properties')
if not props: return
city = props.get('city', 'UNK')
country = props.get('country', 'UNK')
```

This is a draft and I did not test it, also this strongly asserts that your `json object` is based on python `dict object`.

Comment: You're correct, I'm an infant with json.  Thanks for the tips.  I'm not at my usual workstation, but I'll be glad to try this out in a couple of days and follow up.

Comment: I ran through this this morning and it worked the same as above, but with better error handling.  Thanks for the tip!