# When is preferable to use if 'key' in dict: instead of if dict.get('key') is not None:?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been using the following syntax in my code for checking the existence of a key:

```
if dict.get("key") is not None:
    print "key found"
```

However, I have seen in other people's code the following syntax:

```
if 'key' in dict:
   print "key found"
```

I was just wondering which way is best to express a dictionary key null check and if there is an advantage (if any) to using one over the other.

I saw the existing question addressing the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary) of what are the alternatives to using .get() but just want to know if there is any advantage between the two examples I provided.

Comment: Why would you want to send the key to a function and check a default value rather than simply telling it to do what you actually want?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that is a good question, and it is probably suited to someone with more Python experience than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a key entry with the value `None` the two expressions will return different results:

```
>>> d = {'key': None}
>>> d.get("key") is not None
False
>>> 'key' in d
True
```

If you want to check whether the key exists in the dictionary, the `in` operator should be used; it also makes your intention clearer. Additionally, it also works for other sequence types (eg. `list`, `tuple`, etc.)

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name; it shadows the builtin function/type `dict`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am aware of the dict keyword. I used it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @WillemvanKetwich, FYI, `dict` is not a keyword. If it is a keyword, you couldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Apologies - data structure. Interesting sidenote about other sequence types, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

This is better.

```
if 'key' in dict:
   print "key found"
```

Also, as @falsetrue noted, if you have a `None` value in your `dict`, `if d.get('key') is not None` becomes `False` which may not be the intended behaviour.

`dict.get` is useful when you use the value in an expression and want a default value to be used when the `key` is not in the `dict`.

```
d['key'] = 4
a = 5 + d.get('key', 0) # returns 0 if `key` is not in `d`
```

Answer (score 1):

These two ways is different.

`dict.get("key") is not None` means dict has "key" **and** dict["key"] is not None.

`"key" in dict` means dict has "key" and don't care it's value is None or other.

Comment: What I explain is `dict.get("key") is not None` rather than a single `dict.get("key")`.