# Using if/then condition with dictionary object

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and have been working through a handful of activities. Currently I am working with Conditions. I created a dictionary of months and I am using an if/then condition to check if user input is in the dictionary. If the User input is not in the dictionary the output should say 'Bad Month' My code is as follows:

```
months = {1: 'January',
          2: 'February',
          3: 'March',
          4: 'April',
          5: 'May',
          6: 'June',
          7: 'July',
          8: 'August',
          9: 'September',
          10: 'October',
          11: 'November',
          12: 'December'}
choice = input

choice = input('Enter an integer value for a month:')
result = choice

if int(choice) in months:
    print('months')

else:
    print('Bad month')
```

When any integer above 12 is entered the output is 'Bad Month' but when I enter a number from 1-12 the output is just months? I've tried a number of print statements but none that I have tried work. I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you want to print out? The month key?

Comment: You probably want to do `print(months[int(choice)])`.

Comment: Get rid of the condition and do: `print(months.get(int(choice), "Bad month"))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @9.0 He's already doing that check correctly.

Comment: **the output is just months**. What else do you expect `print('months')` to do? What should it do instead?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to cast the user input from what `input()` takes as `string` to an `integer` that you can compare to the `keys()` of your dictionary, and print the corresponding `value` of that `key`.

```
months = {1: 'January',
          2: 'February',
          3: 'March',
          4: 'April',
          5: 'May',
          6: 'June',
          7: 'July',
          8: 'August',
          9: 'September',
          10: 'October',
          11: 'November',
          12: 'December'}

choice = int(input('Enter an integer value for a month: ')) # cast user input to integer

if choice in months:        # check if user input exists in the dictionary keys
    print(months[choice])   # print corresponding key value
else:
    print('Bad month')
```

Demo:

```
Enter an integer value for a month: 4
April
```

Comment: Might as well cast it once and keep the cast in `choice`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go several routes here. If you want to keep your code outline, try

```
if int(choice) in months:
    print('months')

else:
    print('Bad month')
```

As several comments suggested, a better approach might be to use the `get` syntax ([tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)).

```
months.get(input, "Bad Month")
```

Will check for `input` and if it can't find it, return *Bad Month*.  Just `print` what the `get` function returns, and it'll do what you are looking for.

Comment: Why use `in months.keys()` instead of just `in months` as in the question?