# Equivalent of php isset in python

Tags: python, isset

Here is my python code:

```
if onerow[0]['result'] is None or not result['GetOdds'][0]['result']is None:
```

When `result` was empty, it returns this error:

```
if onerow[0]['result'] is None or not result['GetOdds'][0]['result']is None:
KeyError: 0
```

I want a something like `php isset` in python to check a dictionary item

Is there any equivalent function or class in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 4):

The method `dict.get` allows to safely get values from a dictionary.

```
d = {'foo': 1}
d.get('foo') # 1
d.get('bar') # None
```

You can also specify the default value you want `dict.get` to return if `None` happens to be a meaningful value.

```
sentinel = object()

d = {'foo': 1, 'baz': None}
d.get('bar', sentinel) # <object object at 0x...>
```

In your specific case, you have a `KeyError` when trying to access `onerow[0]`. You can use get to return `None` instead.

```
onerow.get(0) # None
```

Comment: what about tuples?

Comment: @Oliver Never mind I suppose it's a different question: how to test if a tuple exists. I did find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: `d.get('baz', 'default')` will return `None`

Comment: @UselesssCat that is why you create a sentinel object

Comment: Maybe you are confusing 'baz' with 'bar'? As I understand the way to do is `d.get('baz', 'default') or 'default'`

Comment: @UselesssCat No, I get that you mean `'baz'`. Although, you want a way to differentiate between `dict.get` returning `None` because nothing was found and because the value is actually `None`. If that is not a concern, the first part of the answer works, if it is then you can create a sentinel object and compare to it. This way if `None` is returned you know the actual value was `None` while if the sentinel is returned, you know no value was found for that key.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I just understood what the sentinel object was for. Maybe if there was an if under line `d.get('bar', sentinel)` like `if value is sentinel: print('value does'n exist')`, it would have been clearer :P