# Ansible: Take action on something that is NOT in your dict, but is in a list

Tags: list, dictionary, apache-kafka, ansible

I have to set the stage a little first. The application is kafka.

**End goal**: I want to be able to make kafka config match what I provide in the dictionary (specifically topics). Adding topics to make kafka match is easy. The part I'm having problem is removing topics from kafka if they are not in the dictionary. The only variable I ened to provide kafka is the "topic name" in order to delete.

I can obtain a list of currently added topics from kafka as a variable we will call {{ existing }}. It looks like this:

```
topic1
topic2
topic3
topic4
```

My dictionary is as follows:

```
kafka_topics:
  topic1:
    partitions: 1
    replication_factor: 1
  topic2:
    partitions: 1
    replication_factor: 1
```

How do I take action on topic3 and topic4 because they are not part of the dict?

At first glance, you just say do a
`if {{existing}} != {{item.key}} then do action`
but that does not work because it only checks 1 key at a time. If the types were reversed the list were a dict, dict was a list) you could easily do it by saying if topics contains existing, then do action.

There has GOT to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Possibly duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Check if each item in `existing` list is in `kafka_topics.keys()`. Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    kafka_topics:
      topic1:
        partitions: 1
        replication_factor: 1
      topic2:
        partitions: 1
        replication_factor: 1
    existing:
      - topic1
      - topic2
      - topic3
      - topic4
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is not in 'kafka_topics'"
      with_items: "{{ existing }}"
      when: item not in kafka_topics.keys()
```

Gets you:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None)
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "topic3 is not in 'kafka_topics'"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "topic4 is not in 'kafka_topics'"
}
```

Replace `debug` with the "action" you want.

---

Alternatively you can use the [`difference` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) on the above data structures.