# Checking whether a key or value exists in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

First of all, thank you for your help in advance. I am novice to coding and currently studying Python using the book, 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python' and I have a conceptual question on multiple assignment. https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter5/

Here are the excerpts from the book:

```
>>> spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age': 7}
>>> 'name' in spam.keys()
True
>>> 'Zophie' in spam.values()
True
>>> 'color' in spam.keys()
False
>>> 'color' not in spam.keys()
True
>>> 'color' in spam
False
```

So I tried,

```
>>> 7 in spam
```

expecting `True`, but got `False`.

Then I tried,

```
>>> 7 in spam.values()
```

which returned `True`.

So, it seems string values work the same way, but integers behave differently.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that **7 is a value, not a key**. `spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age':7}` So if you do:

```
7 in spam >> False
'age' in spam >> True
7 in spam.values() >> True
7 in spam.keys() >> False

foo = {key0 : value0 , key1 : value1 ... keyN: valueN}
```

Take in to account, that in python the `in` looks for dictionary's keys list, not the values list. Unless you specify to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer! Got it!

Answer (score 0):

`In` checks against the keys only, whereas the values are accessible via `dict.values()`, `dict.values()` gives access to the values of a dictionary. Both `.keys()`and `.values()` return an iterable.

For a more elegant/shorter way to check for an existing key you could use `dict.get(key)`. This returns the value of the given key if the key is in the dictionary, and a 'fall-back' return value if not. This 'fall-back' return value is `None` by default (if not specified) or can be set by the programmer by using `dict.get(key, return_if_not_in_dict)`. For a more detailed explanation see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1602934/3991125) or the following code:

```
In [10]: spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age': 7}

In [11]: 'name' in spam
Out[11]: True

In [12]: 'Zophie' in spam
Out[12]: False

In [13]: 'name' in spam.keys()
Out[13]: True

In [14]: 'Zophie' in spam.values()
Out[14]: True

In [15]: type(spam.keys())
Out[15]: dict_keys

In [17]: type(spam.values())
Out[17]: dict_values

In [18]: spam.get('name')
Out[18]: 'Zophie'

In [19]: spam.get('some invalid key')   # returns `None`, so no output here

In [20]: spam.get('some invalid key', 'not in here')
Out[20]: 'not in here'

In [21]: bool(spam.get('name'))
Out[21]: True

In [22]: bool(spam.get('some invalid key'))
Out[22]: False
```