# How to know if something exists in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I'm consuming an API and the info from it would be something like this:

```
"id": "17",
"address": "Av. Nossa Senhora de Copacabana",
"addressComplement": "A",
"number": "945",
"cityId": "2",
"cityName": "Rio de Janeiro",
"state": "Rio de Janeiro",
"uf": "RJ",
"neighborhood": "Copacabana",
"properties": {},
"telephones": [],
"geolocation": {
    "lat": -22.97625,
    "lng": -43.19002
},
```

But, in some records, it doesn't contain the `geolocation` field, so I have to check if `geolocation` exists inside my code.

I was trying to use `hasattr` to do this trick, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the part of my code:

```
if hasattr(i, 'geolocation'):
    address_lat = i['geolocation']['lat']
    address_lng = i['geolocation']['lng']
else:
    address_lat = 0.0
    address_lng = 0.0
```

My thought here is that it will check if in the position of index `i` exist something inside `geolocation`. If there is something, then it returns true and enter inside the condition, else the var will receive `0.0`.

So, am I doing something wrong? Is this the right way to use `hasattr`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: You shouldn't use `0.0` for missing values. It's a valid lat-lng;  `np.nan` or an out of range number (say, 1000) is probably much more appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simpler than that:

```
address_lat = i['geolocation']['lat'] if 'geolocation' in i else 0.0
address_lng = i['geolocation']['ing'] if 'geolocation' in i else 0.0
```

[`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) is useful for checking if an *object* has an *attribute*. This is a more specific case, you just need to check if a *key* is `in` a *dictionary*.

A minor complaint: `i` is a confusing name for a dictionary, at first sight I thought that was an index. Better rename it to something meaningful!

Comment: `.get()` you mean?

Comment: If 'geolocation' does not exist in `i`at all this would nevertheless raise a KeyError?

Comment: yup, I just realised that. It's fixed now, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 9):

You could use the `dict.get` method that allows to supply a default value that will be returned if the key does not exist, e.g. like:

```
geolocation = i.get('geolocation', {"lat": 0., "lng": 0.})
```

Comment: removes the need for `try/except` or `if` check, +1

Answer (score 1):

`hasattr` is usually using for an object.

```
>>> class A:
...     i = 10
...
>>> hasattr(A(), 'i')
True
```

In your case, the best way to check if a key exists in a dictionary
it's to do something like that

```
data = {'geolocation': 0.0}
if 'geolocation' in data:
     ...do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `try except` clause:

```
try:
    address_lat = i['geolocation']['lat']
    address_lng = i['geolocation']['lng']
except KeyError:
    address_lat = 0.0
    address_lng = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get and set the default values for lat and lng if they doesn't exist.

```
geolocation = i.get('geolocation',{"lat": 0,"lng":0})
address_lat = geolocation['lat']
address_lng = geolocation['lng']
```