# How do I find if a variable has been defined?

Tags: robotframework, metaprogramming

How do I find out if a variable has been defined in my Robot Framework script?  I am doing API testing, not UI testing.  I have a complex set up and tear-down sequence and, since I am interacting with multiple computers through the script, it is important to know the current state if a fatal error has occurred.  I could track what I have done with some complex set of meta variables or a variable tracking list, but I would prefer to query if a particular variable has been defined and if so take the appropriate tear-down steps.

A simplified version is something like:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check monitor
    ${monitored}=  Connect to Monitor  ${Monitor IP Address}  ${User name}  ${password}
    ${peer connected}=  Connect to Monitor  ${Peer IP Address}  ${User name}  ${password}
    Get Information from Monitor  ${IP Address}
    Send Info to Peer   ${buffer1}
    Report back to Monitor  ${Monitor IP Address}
```

We are assuming that the tear-down closes the connections.  I want to close any connections that are open, but if I failed to open the peer connection I will close the monitor connection and fail on closing the monitor connection.

I am trying to determine if ${peer connected} is defined.  Can I look into Robot Framework's variable storage to see if it is there (in that dictionary?)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call [Get Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variables) to get a dictionary of all variables, then check whether the variable you're interested in is in the dictionary.

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    ${foo}=        set variable  hello, world
    ${variables}=  Get variables

    Should be true      "\${foo}" in $variables
    Should not be true  "\${bar}" in $variables
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need.  I can inspect for the existence of the necessary variables in this scope and Fail or proceed accordingly.

Comment: What is the difference between calling the ${variables} and $variables? I'm wondering why ${variables} doesn't work, but $variables works.

Comment: @KonstantinV: it is described in the robot framework documentation for the [built-in library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions)

Answer (score 5):

There a pretty straightforward approach - the built-in keyword [Get Variable Value](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variable%20Value) returns python's `None` (by default) if there is no such variable defined:

```
${the var}=    Get Variable Value    ${peer connected}
${is set}=      Set Variable If    """${the var}""" != 'None'    ${True}    ${False}
```

Comment: In case the variable `${the var}` contains the value `None`, which means that variable WAS defined, the condition will not be satisfied cause it contains the value `None`

Answer (score 1):

I am fine with this approach. In case the variable is not defined, the test case does not fail....

```
${variables}  Get variables
${status}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Evaluate   $new_table in $variables
${new_table}  Set variable if  ${status}==${FALSE}  new_tbl  ${new_table}
```

Answer (score 1):

## By this code you can check if variable exist without failing the testcase & you can create as well if you want

```
${var_1}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Variable Should Exist  ${var_1}
IF  '${var_1}' == 'False'
    ${var_1}  set variable  hello-world
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible is:

```pascal
${variables}  Get Variables
IF  "\${dataPluginVersion}" in "${variables}"
  No Operation
ELSE
  ${dataPluginVersion}  Set Variable  0
END
```

Or:

```pascal
${variables}  Get Variables
IF  not "\${dataPluginVersion}" in "${variables}"
  ${dataPluginVersion}  Set Variable  0
END
```

Comment: There must be `variables.keys()` because `variables` is a dict, then it works.

Comment: `keys()`is not the point. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602944/2311167). The point is that `"${variables}"` is a text substitution and that can easily produce errors evaluating the expression (depending on the content). So, better use the [Special $variable syntax](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#special-variable-syntax). I.e. say `IF  "\${dataPluginVersion}" in $variables` without quotes and without curly braces around `variables`. See also @Michal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way:

```
OEM-T01-99-Test-variables
    [Tags]    TEST
    Variable Should Not Exist   \${TESTDEVICE_SSH_CONNECTION}
    Variable Should Exist   \${TEST_NAME}
```

This method is more readable and less verbose than using "Get Variables" keyword, IMHO

Reference: [Robotframework built-in keywords](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Variable%20Should%20Exist)