# Firebase python - How to check if field (property) exists in doc

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-firestore

We have read a document from firebase using Python.

```
 doc_ref           = db.collection(u'collection_name').document(collection_abc)
        doc_fetched    = doc_ref.get()
        if (doc_fetched.exists):
            if (doc_fetched.get('doc_field')):
```

We get the following error

```
KeyError("'doc_field' is not contained in the data")
```

How do we check if doc_field exists in doc_fetched? This document might have some fields populated, and some not populated at the time of read (by design).

We also tried the following with the same error.

```
if (doc_fetched.get('doc_field') != null):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation for [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot), there is a method [to_dict()](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot) that provides the contents of a document as a dictionary.  You can then deal with it just like any other dictionary: [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can simply check the `DocumentSnapshot` object for nullity like this:

```
var doc_ref = db.collection('collection_name').doc(collection_abc);
var getDoc = doc_ref.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
        if(doc.get('yourPropertyName') != null) {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log('yourPropertyName does not exist!');
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
```

Or you can use [to_dict()](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot) method as in the [@Doug Stevenson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61510059/8791788)

Comment: doc.get('yourPropertyName') returns with a KeyError since 'yourPropertyName' is not available. I had to use if ('yourPropertyName' in doc.to_dict() ). Thanks for your suggestion.