# I want to do in while loop and if statematent with an dictionary and return my own values that i assigned with return

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to return the if statements if they equal the value of the dictionary and print the dictionary value not just use == 'HW' and print some text. Right Now I return nothing So I am wondering what I did wrong. How do I get out of the while loop when I give a wrong answer first and then a correct one?

```
from ex45f import live
class adult(live):

    def __init__(self, choose):
        self.choose = choose

    def choices(self):
        options = {
            'HW': 'Hard Working',
            'PA': 'Partying',
            'DE': 'Doing everyting a bit',
            }
#while choose != 'HW' or 'PA' or 'DE':
        while not (self.choose == 'HW' or self.choose == 'PA' or self.choose == 'DE'):
            x = input("""Choose again
> """)
            print(x)
        if self.choose == options['HW']:
            return "You are going to be millionare"
        elif self.choose == options['PA']:
            return "You will have the first year a great life and then you will hate it"
        elif self.choose == options['DE']:
            return "Nothing intersting in life happens."
        else:
            return "Wrong input"

choose = input("""Choose one of those options: HW, PA, DE)
> """)
zw = adult(choose)
zw.choices()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: Although I don’t quite understand what your question is.

Comment: In your `while` loop you're checking `self.choose` but you're only updating `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple of comments:

1. self.choose will either be HW, PA, or DE
   your if statemen checks `if self.choose == options['HW']`.

   options['HW'] is really **"Hard Working"**, so in the case above self.choose will always end at the `else`.
   Your if statements should be:
   `if self.choose == "HW":`
   `if self.choose == "PA":`
   `if self.choose == "DE":`
2. Your `while` loop could look like: `while self.choose not in options:`
3. if self.choose is not in the list, you get a new input and store it in x. `self.choose` remains unchanged. Thus the while loop will be infinite.
   instead of `x = input` do `self.choose = input` so when the user enters one of the correct options, they will leave the while loop.
4. If you want to get the value of `options` add `return "{} The text to return".format(options[self.choose])`
5. Finally, if you have no interest in the terms `Hard Working`, `Partying`, or `Doing everthing a bit`, then just make options a list:
   `options = ["DE", "PA", "HW"]` Then you do not need `options[self.choose]`

I hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me a lot! The only question I still have is that if you want to get the value of options add return "{} The text to return".format(options[self.choose]) doesn't work. I had to change it into print("{} The text to return".format(options[self.choose])). Why doesn't return work?

Comment: Because return only sends it back to the caller. you can either do what you did and put print in the function, or you can try:
print(zw.choices())