# Iterating through dictionary and checking if user input equals a key

Tags: python, dictionary

How would I be able to check if a user input equals a key in my dictionary? This is what I have so far:

```
dict_inventory = {
"Blue Large Gloves": {"Manufacturer": "NA", "Order ID": "PHGLOVLG", "Amount in stock": 20, "Par": "2", "Lot Number": "123456", "Lot Expiration": datetime.date(2023, 3, 5)}, 
"BacT Bottles": {"Manufacturer": "Biomerieux", "Order ID": "NA", "Amount in stock": 2, "Par": 3, "Lot Number":"789456", "Lot Expiration": datetime.date(2021, 5, 26)}, 
"pH Buffer 10": {"Manufacturer" : "ThermoScientific", "Order ID": "NA", "Amount in stock": 10, "Par":10, "Lot Number": "35678", "Lot Expiration": datetime.date(2020, 3, 14)}
}

item_taken = input("Which item was taken from stock?: ")
        for k in dict_inventory:
            if item_taken == dict_inventory[k]:
                user_int = int(input(f"How many {item_taken} were taken from stock?: "))
                dict_inventory[item_taken]["Amount in stock"] -= user_int
            else:
                print("Item does not exist")#
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary answer your question

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
This already exists on Stack Overflow in easily searchable form, and it's included in any tutorial on dicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
dict_inventory = { "Blue Large Gloves": {"Manufacturer": "NA", "Order ID": "PHGLOVLG", "Amount in stock": 20, "Par": "2", "Lot Number": "123456", "Lot Expiration": datetime.date(2023, 3, 5)},
                  "BacT Bottles": {"Manufacturer": "Biomerieux", "Order ID": "NA", "Amount in stock": 2, "Par": 3, "Lot Number":"789456", "Lot Expiration": datetime.date(2021, 5, 26)},
                  "pH Buffer 10": {"Manufacturer" : "ThermoScientific", "Order ID": "NA", "Amount in stock": 10, "Par":10, "Lot Number": "35678", "Lot Expiration": datetime.date(2020, 3, 14)} }

item_taken = input("Which item was taken from stock?: ")
exists=0
for k in dict_inventory:
    if item_taken == k:
        exists=1
if exists==1:
    print('Oh no I loved that.')
    user_int = int(input(f"How many {item_taken} were taken from stock?: "))
    dict_inventory[item_taken]["Amount in stock"] -= user_int
else: print("Item does not exist")
```

Comment: You can delete first loop and replace condition with `if item_taken in dict_inventory`