# Check if python dict value exists

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value-store

So I'm new to dicts and I'm trying to lookup and save usernames inside a json dictionary and I keep getting that the username is not in the dictionary, I've tried a few solutions I found here but none seem to work, is it something with my dict?

```
        username = input("Write your username: ")

            user_data['users'].append({
                'name': f'{username}',
                'highscore': '0',
                'table': ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
                'turn': '1'
            })
            with open('user_data.json', 'w') as file:
                json.dump(user_data, file, indent=4)
```

Tried this and a few similar ones

```
"name" in user_data.values()
```

Comment: Do you mean dict value or dict key?

Comment: why would you use a list? as value of  user_data['users'] ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Dieter so I could append data to it

Comment: @mkrieger had seen that one before posting it didn't work though

Comment: @JoãoBrito - a dictionary is an unordered key - values list, whereby the keys has to be unique. ( maybe a good practice --> give each user an ID instead of using a real (string) name). + yes you can add new values to a dictionary  -->   user_data['users'][username] = { ... } <---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for `name` key in each of the dictionaries in the list that corresponds to the key `users` of the dictionary `user_data` (that was a mouthful).

```py
any('name_to_search_for' == user['name'] for user in user_data['users'])
```

Comment: This might do what OP *asked* for, but not what they *meant*

Comment: @DeepSpace I edited the answer. `name` is indeed ambiguous.

Comment: Doesn't that just return the key?

Comment: @JoãoBrito no, this returns whether your username exists in some dict in your list. Try it yourself! If you want the whole dictionary corresponding to that username, then I can edit the code for that too.

Comment: @kwkt Seemed to work! Thank you very much