# Dictionaries, call value from key

Tags: python

I am trying to grab input and if the dictionary `logins` has a key that matches my input, I want to return the value of that key.

```
logins = {
    'admin':'admin',
    'turtle':'password123'
}

logging = input('username: ')

for logging in logins:
    print(logins.values())
```

Comment: `print(logins[logging])`…?

Comment: @deceze He needs to sanitize for valid inputs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: A quick note for you: when you write "for logging in logins," it means you are iterating through the keys of the dictionary. So, in the first run of the loop, one of the keys of the dictionary will be assigned to the variable "logging". Therefore, logging doesn't contain the input- provided by the user- any more.

Comment: BTW, `logging` is a bad name for that variable. First the username has nothing to do with logging, and second there is the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) in the Python Standard Library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
logins = {
    'admin':'admin',
    'turtle':'password123'
}

logging = input('username: ')

value = logins.get(logging, "Not found")
print(value)
```

Thanks to @deceze for [kind suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022359/dictionaries-call-value-from-key/66022422?noredirect=1#comment116730758_66022422)

If you need an iteration with `for`, try

```
for login in logins:
    #do something with login
    # e.g. if login == input
```

Comment: `try: print(logins[logging]) except KeyError: print('Not found')`…

Comment: `print(logins.get(logging, 'Not found'))`…

Comment: sure, that's better.

Answer (score 4):

No looping necessary, just lookup by key.

```
logging = input('username: ')
value = logins.get(logging)
if value is not None:
    print(value)
else:
    print(f"username {logging!r} was not found")
```

Alternatively:

```
print(logins[logging])
```

however this will raise a KeyError exception if the key `logging` is not in the dictionary

Comment: The question needs to sanitize for existence of key yours returns None if not there

Comment: It returns nothing. It _prints_ `None`.

Comment: Yes but he needs to print only if exists right?

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa: did OP say that? He probably shouldn't print it as it is a password

Comment: He probably shouldn't store passwords in plaintext in the first place?

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa: true.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path. All you need to do is make use of the native property of dictionary to find if the element is in dictionary:

```
logins = {
    'admin':'admin',
    'turtle':'password123'
}

logging = input('username: ')

if logging in logins:
  print(logins[logging])
```