# Accessing list item dynamically in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list (named `Responses`) which contains some dictionary with the following key-value pair:

```
Responses = [
    {'Id':100,'ResponseText1':'aaaa','ResponseText2':'yyyy'},
    {'Id':101,'ResponseText1':'bbbb','ResponseText2': 'zzzz'},
    {'Id':103,'ResponseText1':'cccc'},
    {'Id':104,'ResponseText2': True},
]
```

As you can see here `Id` is a common field for all `dictionary`, but `ResponseText1` and `ResponseText2` are unavailable for some `dictionary`.

I want to separate and detect all the data to push them into my database. My `python` code:

```
for j in Responses:
    print(j['Id'])
    if j['ResponseText1']:
        print(j['ResponseText1'])
    else:
        print("No ResponseText1 is present")
    if j['ResponseText2']:
        print(j['ResponseText2'])
    else:
         print("No ResponseText2 is present")
```

But It says errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
KeyError: 'ResponseText2'
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` or `.get('key', default)`, not `['key']` access to prevent KeyErrors

example of both

```
for j in Responses:
    print(j['Id'])
    text1 = j.get('ResponseText1')
    if text1 is not None:
        print(text1)
    else:
        print("No ResponseText1 is present")

    if 'ResponseText2' in j:
        print(j['ResponseText2'])
    else:
         print("No ResponseText2 is present")
```