# Get data for JSON Python second List

Tags: python, json, zendesk-api

Hoping you are good
I am trying to get data from zendisk by API and Python Json
i can get any data Value under Audits LikeTicket_id and auther_id but when tried get data under Events such as Body
keep get this error

print(audit['body'])

KeyError: 'body'

JSON Output

```
{
   "audits":[
      {
         "id":1727876301271,
         "ticket_id":54010951,
         "created_at":"2021-10-21T10:58:06Z",
         "author_id":12306596687,
         "metadata":{
            "system":{
               "client":"GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.29.0 PHP/7.1.2",
               "ip_address":"x.x.x.x",
               "location":"Boardman, OR, United States",
               "latitude":45.8491,
               "longitude":-119.7143
            },
            "custom":{
               
            }
         },
         "events":[
            {
               "id":1727876301291,
               "type":"Comment",
               "author_id":366289833251,
               "body":"Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,\n\nIn unserer Bestellung fehlt das Kleid, es war nicht mit dabei, obwohl es hätte drin sein müssen.\nFreundliche Grüße",
            
               "attachments":[
                  
               ],
               "audit_id":1727876301271
            },
            {
               "id":1727876301311,
               "type":"Create",
               "value":"366289833251",
               "field_name":"requester_id"
            },
```

Python Code

```
import requests
import csv
# Settings
auth = 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx'
view_tickets = []
view_id = 214459268
view_audits = []
ticket_id = 54010951
view_events =[]
print(f'Getting tickets from ticket_id ID {ticket_id}')
url = f'https://xxxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/54010951/audits.json'
while url:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
    page_data = response.json()
    audits = page_data['audits']     # extract the "tickets" list from the page
    view_audits.extend(audits)
    url = page_data['next_page']


for audit in audits:

    print(audit['body'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you're overwriting, not adding, to audits right? (in this line: `audits = page_data['audits']`). I don't think that makes sense, but it's hard to know your intent.

To fix the error itself, your json structure has the `body` key inside the events `key`. So you can access it with:

```
print(audit['events'][0]['body'])
```

or, using another loop:

```
for audit in audits:
    for event in audit['events']
        print(event['body'])
```

You might get an error for the 2nd one because it doesn't appear to have the `body` key. You can add an if statement to handle that if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much 
yes I overwriting for Reason  
'    c+=1 # to found which key
    print(c)
    try:
        print(audit['events'][0]['value'])
    except KeyError:
         continue'

Comment: Looks like the objects under events have very different forms. To avoid throwing errors, just check if the key exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary before calling it. The first object has a `body` key, while the second has `value`.