# what is the way to write code in python to print only sai details?

Tags: python-3.x

In the file there is a JSON data I'm trying to retrieve data from "sai" only
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r7tnZjFSvggfkI890vgmRmiv16_kAbY4/view?usp=sharing

```py
import json
with open("student_detailsdb.json","r") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
for i in data:
    print(i["sai"])
```

Comment: Please include the JSON itself in your post, not as a link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the "sai" key present in the iteration (i), then it will print only sai details

```
import json
with open("student_detailsdb.json","r") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
for i in data:
    if "sai" in i:
       print(i["sai"])
```

Comment: @SaiKiran Welcome!. Pls, upvote and accept the answers, if it is helped you.