# In Python, How do you loop through a list if one value is missing in that list?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

My goal is to create a dataframe based on the 'viewCount',  'likeCount', 'favoriteCount' and 'commentCount'.

The code below works gives 25 values for 'viewCount',  'favoriteCount', and 'commentCount', but I get an error for 'likeCount' because 'likeCount' has 1 missing value in its list.

How can I create an "if, then statement" that will place a 0 count into the 'likeCount' list when the programs see's that value doesn't exist.

The if then statement below is what I've tried, but I'm getting a
KeyError: 'likeCount' error

```
x=0
y=0
viewCount = []
likeCount = []
favoriteCount = []
commentCount = []

while (x < len(response2)):
    viewCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'])
    favoriteCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['favoriteCount'])
    commentCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount'])
    if not (response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']):
        likeCount.append(0) 
    else:
        likeCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'])
    x=x+1
    
            
#print(video_title, video_id)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'viewCount': viewCount,'favoriteCount': favoriteCount,
            'commentCount': commentCount, 'likeCount' : likeCount} )
df2
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

     10     favoriteCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['favoriteCount'])
     11     commentCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount'])
---> 12     if not (response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']):
     13         likeCount.append(0)
     14     else:

KeyError: 'likeCount'
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace of the error? Or at least what line it is on

Comment: Also, could you please post a sample of what response2 looks like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `response2` doesn't have right key-value pair. Maybe you could try using a controlled exception.

For example:

```
try:
    likeCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'])
except:
    likeCount.append(0)
```

Also, I would strongly suggest using snake_case instead of camelCase for naming variables. In python generally snake_case is used for functions and variables, while camelCase is reserved for classes.

Hopefully my answer helped you.

Comment: Good callout with the snake vs camel case.

Comment: Copied, pasted, and it worked right away. except is acting as an exception? It works great, thank you!

Comment: Whenever you use try-except if there's an error inside the `try:` python handles it so that your program doesn't crash. Then it runs the code inside the `except:` and afterwards it continues with execution. You could also catch the exception and work with it by using except as follows `except Exception as e:`

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be certain, but you are likely getting the error because using ['likeCount'] assumes that index is present in the object. Here is a different write:

```
    if not (response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']):
        likeCount.append(0) 
    else:
        likeCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'])
```

so that it should work:

```
    likeCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics'].get('likeCount', 0))
```

This utilizes the get function (which won't error if the index is not found) and sets the default value to 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get this code to work because I didn't know where to place '    likeCount.append(response2[x]['items'][0]['statistics'].get('likeCount', 0))
'. Should this line of code be placed under if not or else? Thank you

Comment: It should replace the if not else block