# How can I convert this into list comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary in which I need to append new values with keys from another dictionary, though i made the for loop working, I'm asked to make a list comprehension for it. can someone help me out in this

Code:

```
for key, value in functionParameters.items():
    if type(value) in [int, float, bool, str]:
       if key not in self.__variables:
          self.__variables[key] = value
```

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: `__variables`? I doubt it's a good idea messing with that. And why use a list comprehension. What's the benefit?

Comment: You aren't comprehending a list so you don't need a list comprehension

Comment: i saw this code piece : ` self.__variables = {**self.__variables, **{i: temp.get(i) for i in temp if  i not in self.startlocals and i[0] != '_' and type(temp[i]) in [int, float, bool, str]}} ` and wanted to make like this

Comment: You're dealing with a dictionary, so how would a list comprehension be relevant? A dictionary comprehension makes the most sense, and the one you just had in your comment works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to create/update a `dict`, you need to use [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) -

```
self.__variables = {**self.__variables, **{k: v for k, v in functionParameters.items() if type(v) in [int, float, bool, str] and k not in self.__variables}}
```

Explanation -

- `z = {**x, **y}` merges dicts `x` and `y` into a new dict `z`.
- `{k: v for k, v in functionParameters.items() if type(v) in [int, float, bool, str] and k not in self.__variables}` mimics your `for` loop and creates a new `dict`
- We are merging the original `self.__variables` dict with newly created dict above and saving it as `self.__variables`.

here's a simplifed working example -

```
functionParameters = {"20": 20, "string_val": "test", "float": 12.15, "pre-existing_key": "new-val", "new_type": [12, 12]}
variables = {"old_key": "val", "pre-existing_key": "val"}
variables = {**variables, **{k: v for k, v in functionParameters.items() if type(v) in [int, float, bool, str] and k not in variables}}
print(variables)
```

Prints -

```
{'old_key': 'val', 'pre-existing_key': 'val', '20': 20, 'string_val': 'test', 'float': 12.15}
```

Note that the value of the `pre-existing_key` key in output and missing `new_type` key since corresponding value is a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to check if a `key` is used in an array or not in this way:

```
if key not in self.__variables: # not correct
```

if you do this **it checks if the** `key` **exists** as a value inside `self.__variables`

I don't know your reason to do this!, but you can use `try & except` to handle it like this:

```py
for key, value in functionParameters.items():
    if type(value) in [int, float, bool, str]:
       try: 
          if self.__variables[key] is not None:
             self.__variables[key] = value
       except Exception ignored:
             pass
```

Comment: `key not in self.__variables` for a dictionary checks if that is the *key* of the dictionary: a dictionary is an iterable of its *keys*, not its values: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602964/67579

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to use `dict comprehension` for this. The code should be like this

```
self.__variables = {**self.__variables, **{key: value for key, value in functionParameters.items() if type(value) in [int, float, bool, str] and key not in self.__variables}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update with:

```
self.__variables.update({
    key: value
    for key, value in functionParameters.items()
    if key not in self.__variables and type(value) in [int, float, bool, str]
})
```