# Handle KeyError exception and get dictionary name which caused the trouble

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

`KeyError` exception object contains `args` attribute. This is a list and it contains a key name which user tries to access within a dictionary.
Is it possible to figure out dictionary name which does not contain that key and which caused  an exception while trying to access the key within it?

Example

```
data = {"my_key": "my_value"}

try:
    data["unknown_key"] except KeyError as e:
    print("key name: ", e.args[0])
    print("dictionary name: ", e.???) # Here I would need to know the the name of a variable which stores the dictionary is "data"
```

Comment: No. A dict could have many names, or none. What would your use case be anyway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: I need to implement dynamic error handling for all KeyErrors. All dictionaries represent known structures/objects and based on the dictionary name (variable name which stores a dictionary) I can dynamically figure out which object is missing.
In my example above, in the exception handling routine I would need to know what dictionary name is "data".

Comment: There's no intrinsic name for a dictionary – after all, multiple names could refer to the same object. What do you actually need to do, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda hack this with Python 3.11+, since the traceback [contains fine-grained information](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#whatsnew311-pep657) about where the error happened.

```
import ast
import linecache
import traceback

data = {"my_key": "my_value"}
flurk = data
try:
    data["flep"] = data["my_key"] + flurk["unknown_key"]
except KeyError as e:
    # Find the last frame where the exception occurred, formatted as a FrameSummary
    err_frame = traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(e).stack[-1]
    if err_frame.lineno == getattr(err_frame, "end_lineno", -1):  # If we can reliably find the line,
        # ... read the line,
        line = linecache.getline(err_frame.filename, err_frame.lineno)
        # find the "marked segment" in it,
        fragment = line[err_frame.colno:err_frame.end_colno]
        # ... and parse it as an expression.
        expr: ast.Expression = ast.parse(fragment, mode='eval')
        # Check we're dealing with a subscript (index) node...
        assert isinstance(expr.body, ast.Subscript)
        # ... and extract the main parts of the expression.
        subscriptee = ast.unparse(expr.body.value)
        subscript = ast.unparse(expr.body.slice)
    else:
        subscriptee = None  # No idea
        subscript = e.args[0]  # Just use the exception message
    raise RuntimeError(f"KeyError with {subscriptee=!r}, {subscript=!r}") from e
```

prints out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_679.py", line 8, in <module>
    data["flep"] = data["my_key"] + flurk["unknown_key"]
                                    ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'unknown_key'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_679.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(f"KeyError with {subscriptee=!r}, {subscript=!r}") from e
RuntimeError: KeyError with subscriptee='flurk', subscript="'unknown_key'"
```

so you can see the subscriptee name is `flurk`.